# python modify item in list, save back in list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a hunch that I need to access an item in a list (of strings), modify that item (as a string), and put it back in the list in the same index

I'm having difficulty getting an item back into the same index

```
for item in list:
    if "foo" in item:
        item = replace_all(item, replaceDictionary)
        list[item] = item
        print item
```

now I get an error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

due to this line `list[item] = item`

which makes sense! but I do not know how to put the item back into the list at that same index using python

what is the syntax for this? Ideally the for loop can keep track of the index I am currently at

Comment: Why do you have to do it in place in the list?  My initial reaction was to use a list comprehension: 

res = [ replace_all(item,replaceDictionary) for item in list if 'foo' in item ]

Comment: thats pretty crafty, but how is that any different than this?

Comment: The only issue i can see is that you're attempting to reference a list item by using the item itself not the index of the item.  Looks fine other than that.

Also, you're modifying the list item before referencing it.  Could be an issue for dictionaries.

Comment: General question about the above, is replace_all deprecated or something? Or am I missing that it's a custom function that's not defined in the code.

Comment: Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop/4082739

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You could do this:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(list):
   if 'foo' in item:
       item = replace_all(...)
       list[idx] = item
```

Comment: `ValueError: too many values to unpack` , I have been suspecting that I have been running out of space for my lists, is there a way to pre-manage how much space to address to dive further into the list? (might be a new question)

Comment: @RD.: You sure you've used enumerate?

Comment: ah, did not notice that in thise post. This seems to have worked. Although I run into the memory space issue again when I try to join that into a string `listString = ''.join(list)` , for some reason it decides to print out how far it goes to the console, and does not complete the rest of the program

Comment: Got this with Python 3: 
NameError: name 'replace_all' is not defined

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the enumerate function: [python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
for place, item in enumerate(list):
    if "foo" in item:
        item = replace_all(item, replaceDictionary)
        list[place] = item
        print item
```

Also, it's a bad idea to use the word list as a variable, due to it being a reserved word in python.

Since you had problems with enumerate, an alternative from the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) library:

```
for place, item in itertools.zip(itertools.count(0), list):
    if "foo" in item:
        item = replace_all(item, replaceDictionary)
        list[place] = item
        print item
```

Answer (score 7):

A common idiom to change every element of a list looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(L)):
    item = L[i]
    # ... compute some result based on item ...
    L[i] = result
```

This can be rewritten using enumerate() as:

```
for i, item in enumerate(L):
    # ... compute some result based on item ...
    L[i] = result
```

See [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html).

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3:

```
ListOfStrings = []
ListOfStrings.append('foo')
ListOfStrings.append('oof')
for idx, item in enumerate(ListOfStrings):
    if 'foo' in item:
        ListOfStrings[idx] = "bar"
```