# Python: What is the right way to modify list elements?

Tags: data-structures, python

I've this list with tuples:

```
l = [('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f')]
```

And two parameters: a key value, and a new value to modify. For example,

```
key = 'a'
new_value= 'B' # it means, modify with 'B' the value in tuples where there's an 'a'
```

I've this two options (both works):

```
f = lambda t,k,v: t[0] == k and (k,v) or t 
new_list = [f(t,key,new_value) for t in l]
print new_list
```

and

```
new_list = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    elem = l.pop()
    if elem[0] == key:
        new_list.append((key,new_value))
    else:
        new_list.append(elem)
print new_list
```

But, i'm new in Python, and don't know if its right.

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: If you want dictionary-like features, use a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Obviously this means keys have to be unique; I don't know if that goes against your requirements

Comment: Thank you, i know dictionary. It's a more general question, how to modify elements in a list.

Comment: This doesn't modify a. List, it creates a new copy. Which do you want?

Comment: @Kathy you're right! I'd like to know both. to modify i'd do pop(i), and insert(i,x). What do you think?

Comment: there are different ways to modify lists in python because different situations work best with the different approaches. There is no general answer to the best way to modify a list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify list entries during for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify existing list just use list assignment, e.g.

```
>>> l = [('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f')]
>>> l[0] = ('a','B')
>>> print l
[('a', 'B'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

I would usually prefer to create a new list using comprehension, e.g.

```
[(key, new_value) if x[0] == key else x for x in l]
```

But, as the first comment has already mentioned, it sounds like you are trying to make a list do something which you should really be using a dict for instead.

Comment: O.o Are you sure you did not mean `l[0] = ('a','B')`?

Comment: o_O  indeed ..  for some stupid reason i was thinking of a flattened list, but i wrote the tuples anyway.  thanks.

Comment: Really simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is one solution involving altering the items in-place.

```
def replace(list_, key, new_value):
    for i, (current_key, current_value) in enumerate(list_):
        if current_key == key:
            list_[i] = (key, new_value)
```

Or, to append if it's not in there,

```
def replace_or_append(list_, key, new_value):
    for i, (current_key, current_value) in enumerate(list_):
        if current_key == key:
            list_[i] = (key, new_value)
            break
    else:
        list_.append((key, new_value))
```

Usage:

```
>>> my_list = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
>>> replace(my_list, 'a', 'B')
>>> my_list
[('a', 'B'), ('c', 'd')]
```

If you want to create a new list, a list comprehension is easiest.

```
>>> my_list = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
>>> find_key = 'a'
>>> new_value = 'B'
>>> new_list = [(key, new_value if key == find_key else value) for key, value in my_list]
>>> new_list
[('a', 'B'), ('c', 'd')]
```

And if you wanted it to append if it wasn't there,

```
>>> if len(new_list) == len(my_list):
...     new_list.append((find_key, new_value))
```

(Note also I've changed your variable name from `l`; `l` is too easily confused with `I` and `1` and is best avoided. Thus saith PEP8 and I agree with it.)

Answer (score 3):

To create a new list, a list comprehension would do:

```
In [102]: [(key,'B' if key=='a' else val) for key,val in l]
Out[102]: [('a', 'B'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

To modify the list in place:

```
l = [('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f')]

for i,elt in enumerate(l):
    key,val=elt
    if key=='a':
        l[i]=(key,'B')
print(l)              
# [('a', 'B'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know those "inline ifs" nor enumerate function. Thanks!

Comment: @santiagobasulto: glad I could help. The "inline ifs" are called [conditional expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) or ternary expressions in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the approach I would use.

```
>>> l = [('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f')]
>>> key = 'a'
>>> new_value= 'B'
>>> for pos in (index for index, (k, v) in enumerate(l) if k == key):
...     l[pos] = (key, new_value)
...     break
... else:
...     l.append((key, new_value))
... 
>>> l
[('a', 'B'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

This looks an awful lot like an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), though; key-value pairs with preserved ordering.  You might want to take a look at that and see if it suits your needs

Edit: Replaced `try:`...`except StopIteration:` with `for:`...`break`...`else:` since that might look a bit less weird.

Comment: You do go in for a complicated solution!

Comment: I don't consider this to be complicated at all.  `list.index` is not available because we're looking for an element that is *in some way similar* to the key, rather than equal to the key.  `enumerate` is pretty normal, and I know of no alternative idiom to get the *first element* from a generator besides `<generator ...>.next()` and catching the exception when not found.  Other alternatives would either be needlessly wordy, or generate intermediate lists.

Comment: I would call it complicated in the way that the Zen of Python talks of complex being better than complicated. When there is a simple solution - iterating with a full `for` loop rather than using `<generator>.next()` and having to deal with catching a `StopIteration` - it's often better. I had to think briefly about what your solution was doing to verify its correctness, whereas I can look at my solution or the other similar ones that have been posted and understand what is being done immediately. It seems to me that error in the `for-if` style would be much more obvious.

Comment: Interesting solution and discussion! Thank you!