# What is a better pythonic version of this conditional deleting?

Tags: python, indexing

i am refreshing my python (2.7) and i am discovering iterators and generators.
As i understood, they are an efficient way of navigating over values without consuming too much memory.
So the following code do some kind of logical indexing on a list: 
removing the values of a list L that triggers a False conditional statement represented here by the function f.

I am not satisfied with my code because I feel this code is not optimal for three reasons:

- I read somewhere that it is better to use a for loop than a while loop. 
  However, in the usual `for i in range(10)`, i can't modify the value of 'i' because it seems that the iteration doesn't care.
- Logical indexing is pretty strong in matrix-oriented languages, and there should be a way to do the same in python (by hand granted, but maybe better than my code).
- Third reason is just that i want to use generator/iterator on this example to help me understand.

Third reason is just that i want to use generator/iterator on this example to help me understand.

TL;DR : Is this code a good pythonic way to do logical indexing ?

```
#f string -> bool
def f(s):
    return 'c' in s

L=['','a','ab','abc','abcd','abcde','abde']  #example
length=len(L)
i=0
while i < length:
    if not f(L[i]): #f is a conditional statement (input string output bool)
        del L[i]
        length-=1 #cut and push leftwise

    else:
        i+=1
    print 'Updated list is :', L
    print length
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, in particular that `if` statement. What is the `else` associated with: the `if` or the `while``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never modify a list with `del`, `pop` or other methods that mutate the length of the list while iterating over it. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939341/why-does-a-for-loop-with-pop-method-or-del-statement-not-iterate-over-all-list) for more information.

The "pythonic" way to filter a list is to use reassignment and either a list comprehension or the built-in `filter` function:

List comprehension:

```
>>> [item for item in L if f(item)]
['abc', 'abcd', 'abcde']
```

> i want to use generator/iterator on this example to help me understand

The `for item in L` part *is* implicitly making use of the iterator protocol. Python lists are iterable, and `iter(somelist)` returns an iterator .

```
>>> from collections import Iterable, Iterator
>>> isinstance([], Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance([], Iterator)
False
>>> isinstance(iter([]), Iterator)
True
```

`__iter__` is not only being called when using a traditional for-loop, but also when you use a list comprehension:

```
>>> class mylist(list):
...     def __iter__(self):
...         print('iter has been called')
...         return super(mylist, self).__iter__()
... 
>>> m = mylist([1,2,3])
>>> [x for x in m]
iter has been called
[1, 2, 3]
```

Filtering:

```
>>> filter(f, L)
['abc', 'abcd', 'abcde']
```

In Python3, use `list(filter(f, L))` to get a list.

Of course, to filter a list, Python needs to iterate over it, too:

```
>>> filter(None, mylist())
iter has been called
[]
```

Comment: So, to mutate the original list, one should write L=list(filter(f,L)) (in 3.0) and L=filter(f,L) in 2.7 ?

Comment: @VictorIletRAM yes. Technically speaking, you reassign the name L to the new list you want, not mutate the original L.

Comment: That's why i was puzzled and wrote my function, which is obviously not as smart as Python filter.

When asked for a mutation, if a reassignment is enough, i'm cool with it.

Thx !

Comment: @VictorIletRAM no problem

Answer (score 3):

This code has a few problems, but the main one is that you must never modify a list you're iterating over. Rather, you create a new list from the elements that match your condition. This can be done simply in a for loop:

```
newlist = []
for item in L:
    if f(item):
        newlist.append(item)
```

which can be shortened to a simple list comprehension:

```
newlist = [item for item in L if f(item)]
```

Comment: Okay. I was feeling like you could modify a list when iterating over it if you knew what you were doing. The list comprehension is the kind of code i was searching for.

However, your solution does not mutate the original list L. I don't feel like just writing 'L=[item for item in L if f(item)]' does the job. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Well, you could do `L[:] = [item for item in L if f(item)]`, which *does* mutate the list.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) is what you're after:

```
newlist = filter(lambda x: not f(x), L)
```

[`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) filters (...) an iterable and only keeps the items for which a predicate returns `True`. In your case `f(..)` is not quite the predicate but `not f(...)`.

Simpler:

```
def f(s):
   return 'c' not in s

newlist = filter(f, L)
```

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: Note that this is `O(n)` in space.

Comment: Still better than moving elements in a list around like OP's solution, which is O(n^2)

Comment: When mutating, i need to write L[:]=filter(f,L). Reassignements mimics mutable only if you work in the same environment.
How does this change complexity ?

Answer (score 0):

"The python way" to do it would be to use a generator expression:

```
# list comprehension
L = [l for l in L if f(l)]
# alternative generator comprehension
L = (l for l in L if f(l))
```

It depends on your context if a list or a generator is "better" (see e.g. [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)). Because your source data is coming from a list, there is no real benefit of using a generator here.

Comment: The generator is not quite the same; you don't get a list out of it, unless you explicitly call `list(L)`. But if you do that you might as well have used the list comprehension in the first place.

Comment: While it's not the same you can iterate over a generator just like a list, so if you only want to do that a generator is "enough". Of course if you want/need a list the list comprehension is "better".

Answer (score 0):

For simply deleting elements, especially if the original list is no longer needed, just iterate backwards:

**Python 2.x**:

```
for i in xrange(len(L) - 1, -1, -1):
    if not f(L[i]):
        del L[i]
```

**Python 3.x**:

```
for i in range(len(L) - 1, -1, -1):
    if not f(L[i]):
        del L[i]
```

By iterating from the end, the "next" index does not change after deletion and a `for` loop is possible. Note that you should use the `xrange` generator in Python 2, or the `range` generator in Python 3, to save memory*.

In cases where you must iterate forward, use your given solution above.

*Note that Python 2's `xrange` will break if there are >= 2 ** 32 - 1 elements. Python 3's `range`, as well as the less efficient Python 2's `range` do not have this limitation.