# How does Python manage a 'for' loop internally?

Tags: python, for-loop, data-structures

I'm trying to learn Python, and I started to play with some code:

```py
a = [3,4,5,6,7]
for b in a:
    print(a)
    a.pop(0)
```

And the output is:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[5, 6, 7]
```

I know that's **not** a good practice change data structures while I'm looping on it, but I want to understand how Python manage the iterators in this case.

The principal question is: How does it know that it has to finish the loop if I'm changing the state of `a`?

Comment: you should print `b` as well, that would give you more clues

Comment: Python loops over the list on demand. Means that in each iteration it assigns the respective item to the throwaway variable and continue the iteration until it encounters the end of the list or raise an `IndexError`.
Answering to how python knows it has to finish the loop if you're changing list, it's all based on encountering the last item or raising an `IndexError`. By changing the list you can just shorten or extend the loop.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939341/why-does-a-for-loop-with-pop-method-or-del-statement-not-iterate-over-all-list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols

Comment: Python does not promise this behavior. A future version might give you a dict-like `RuntimeError: list changed size during iteration`.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for learning Python 2? If not, you should be learning Python 3.

Comment: So list contents are re evaluated at every iteration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

kjaquier and Felix have talked about the iterator protocol, and we can see it in action in your case:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> iterator = iter(L)
>>> iterator
<list_iterator object at 0x101231f28>
>>> next(iterator)
1
>>> L.pop()
3
>>> L
[1, 2]
>>> next(iterator)
2
>>> next(iterator)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

From this we can infer that `list_iterator.__next__` has code that behaves something like:

```
if self.i < len(self.list):
    return self.list[i]
raise StopIteration
```

It does not naively get the item. That would raise an `IndexError` which would bubble to the top:

```
class FakeList(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        raise IndexError

for i in FakeList():  # Raises `IndexError` immediately with a traceback and all
    print(i)
```

Indeed, looking at `listiter_next` in [the CPython source](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c) (thanks Brian Rodriguez):

```
if (it->it_index < PyList_GET_SIZE(seq)) {
    item = PyList_GET_ITEM(seq, it->it_index);
    ++it->it_index;
    Py_INCREF(item);
    return item;
}

Py_DECREF(seq);
it->it_seq = NULL;
return NULL;
```

Although I don't know how `return NULL;` eventually translates into a `StopIteration`.

Comment: "Although I don't know how return NULL; eventually translates into a StopIteration" It doesn't. `StopIteration` becomes `NULL` in `PyIter_Next` (and possibly in other places that may implement the iterator protocol themselves. Haven't checked further)

Comment: @3Doubloons I'm not sure what you mean, `NULL` *does* translate to `StopIteration`. It is explicitly tested for in the callee of `listiter_next` and the exception is set if no other error has occurred.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard: What I'm reading in PyIter_Next (and builtins.all and list.extend for a second opinion), is that when tp_iternext returns NULL, the C code checks if there was an exception. If there was and it was a StopIteration, it clears it (because that's normal). Based on that (and only that), it seems to me that a C implementation of `__next__` simply returns NULL without setting an exception to stop. It's only Python code that needs to raise StopIteration, because it can't return NULL (None is not NULL, it is Py_None)

Comment: @3Doubloons The slot for `tp_iternext` is filled by a descriptor that sets `PyExc_StopIteration` so, even though the actual function that's set to `tp_iternext` isn't setting the exception, it's wrapped by something that does. That's with what I disagreed when you said `NULL` doesn't translate to `StopIteration`. :-)

Comment: Ah, yes. I see it now. Hidden deep inside typeobject.c, `wrap_next` raises StopIteration if the actual tp_iternext returned NULL without an exception. Mystery solved

Answer (score 14):

The reason why you shouldn't do that is precisely so you don't have to rely on how the iteration is implemented.

But back to the question. Lists in Python are array lists. They represent a continuous chunk of allocated memory, as opposed to linked lists in which each element in allocated independently. Thus, Python's lists, like arrays in C, are optimized for random access. In other words, the most efficient way to get from element n to element n+1 is by accessing to the element n+1 directly (by calling `mylist.__getitem__(n+1)` or `mylist[n+1]`).

So, the implementation of `__next__` (the method called on each iteration) for lists is just like you would expect: the index of the current element is first set at 0 and then increased after each iteration.

In your code, if you also print `b`, you will see that happening:

```
a = [3,4,5,6,7]
for b in a:
    print a, b
    a.pop(0)
```

Result :

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 3
[4, 5, 6, 7] 5
[5, 6, 7] 7
```

Because :

- At iteration 0, `a[0] == 3`.
- At iteration 1, `a[1] == 5`.
- At iteration 2, `a[2] == 7`.
- At iteration 3, the loop is over (`len(a) < 3`)

Answer (score 2):

We can easily see the sequence of events by using a little helper function `foo`:

```
def foo():
    for i in l:
        l.pop()
```

and `dis.dis(foo)` to see the Python byte-code generated. Snipping away the not-so-relevant opcodes, your loop does the following:

```
          2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (l)
          4 GET_ITER
    >>    6 FOR_ITER                12 (to 20)
          8 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

         10 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (l)
         12 LOAD_ATTR                1 (pop)
         14 CALL_FUNCTION            0
         16 POP_TOP
         18 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
```

That is, it get's the `iter` for the given object (`iter(l)` a specialized iterator object for lists) and loops until `FOR_ITER` signals that it's time to stop. Adding the juicy parts, here's what `FOR_ITER` does:

```
PyObject *next = (*iter->ob_type->tp_iternext)(iter);
```

which essentially is:

```
list_iterator.__next__()
```

this (finally<sup>*</sup>) goes through to `listiter_next` which performs the index check as @Alex using the original sequence `l` during the check.

```
if (it->it_index < PyList_GET_SIZE(seq))
```

when this fails, `NULL` is returned which signals that the iteration has finished. In the meantime a `StopIteration` exception is set which is silently suppressed in the `FOR_ITER` op-code code:

```
if (!PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_StopIteration))
    goto error;
else if (tstate->c_tracefunc != NULL)
    call_exc_trace(tstate->c_tracefunc, tstate->c_traceobj, tstate, f);
PyErr_Clear();  /* My comment: Suppress it! */
```

so whether you change the list or not, the check in `listiter_next` will ultimately fail and do the same thing.

<sup>*For anyone wondering, `listiter_next` is a descriptor so there's a little function wrapping it. In this specific case, that function is `wrap_next` which makes sure to set `PyExc_StopIteration` as an exception when `listiter_next` returns `NULL`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the for loop uses the iterator protocol. You can manually create and use the iterator as follows:

```
In [16]: a = [3,4,5,6,7]
    ...: it = iter(a)
    ...: while(True):
    ...:     b = next(it)
    ...:     print(b)
    ...:     print(a)
    ...:     a.pop(0)
    ...:
3
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
5
[4, 5, 6, 7]
7
[5, 6, 7]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-116cdcc742c1> in <module>()
      2 it = iter(a)
      3 while(True):
----> 4     b = next(it)
      5     print(b)
      6     print(a)
```

The for loop stops if the iterator is exhausted (raises `StopIteration`).