# What is the reason behind this kind of behaviour when modifying elements while iterating through a python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

In the code below, modification of the first type changes the original list, while in the second list stays intact. Why is the behaviour the way it is?

```
temp = [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},{"e":"f"},{"a":"c"}]

for item in temp:
    if "a" in item:
        item["a"] = "x"
print(temp)
```

```
temp = [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},{"e":"f"},{"a":"c"}]

for item in temp:
    item  = {}
print(temp)
```

Output for the first one is `[{'a': 'x'}, {'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}, {'a': 'x'}]`

and for the second one is `[{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}, {'a': 'c'}]`

Python version is 3.6.5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864393/modify-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for item in temp:
    item  = {}
```

In every iteration the list element `item` is discarded, and instead a new local variable (that just in chance happens to be called `item` as well) is created and assigned with an empty dict, which in turn is discarded as well. The original list is not affected at all.

This can be visualized with `id`, which returns the memory address of the object:

```
temp = [{}]
for item in temp:
    print(id(item))
    item = {}
    print(id(item))
```

Outputs

```
2704138237016
2704138237816
```

Notice how we are getting 2 different ids. 1 for the dict in the list, and another for the new dict created inside the loop.

Compared to

```
for item in temp:
    if "a" in item:
        item["a"] = "x"
```

here `item` is never reassigned with something else (no line says `item = ...`), so `item` always points to dict in the original list. You are assigning to the `'a'` key of that original `item` dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you're accessing the dictionaries and modifying it. In the second example, when you do `item  = {}`, you're saying that the local variable item now points to an empty dictionary. But that doesn't modify the `temp` array.

The correct way to do what the second example is trying to do is:

```
for index in range(len(temp)):
    temp[index] = {}
```

Comment: The Pythonic way to write `for index in range(len(temp)):` is `for index, _ in enumerate(temp):`.

Answer (score 2):

to get a better understanding you can have a look at the similar code:

```
temp = [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},{"e":"f"},{"a":"c"}]

for index in range(len(temp)):
    item = temp[index] # linked with temp
    if 'a' in item:
        # equivalent with temp[index]['a'] = 'x'
        item['a'] = 'x'

print(temp) 

#########################################################

temp = [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},{"e":"f"},{"a":"c"}]

for index in range(len(temp)):
    item = temp[index] # linked with temp
    item = {} # dosen't link at all with temp / new object 

print(temp)
```

output:

```
[{'a': 'x'}, {'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}, {'a': 'x'}]
[{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}, {'a': 'c'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Behaviour of second example is appropriately documented in Python built-in help. Just:

```
>>> help('for')
```

Excerpt from help:

> The for-loop makes assignments to the variables in the target list.
>   This overwrites all previous assignments to those variables including
>   those made in the suite of the for-loop:

```
for i in range(10):
       print(i)
       i = 5             # this will not affect the for-loop
                         # because i will be overwritten with the next
                         # index in the range
```