# getting type error:object of type 'NoneType' has no len(). and it also not printing the sequence after the for operation

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def reverse(seq):
    k=len(seq)

    for i in range(0,k):
        seq.append(seq.pop(i))
    print(seq)
reverse(reverse([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

getting type error:object of type 'NoneType' has no len(). and it also not printing the sequence after the for operation

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. Printing is not returning.

Comment: @muyustan seq is the param

Comment: You have a bigger problem with your algorithm anyway, as `reverse([1,2,3,4,5])` gives `[2, 4, 1, 5, 3]`. As a general rule, avoid modifying a list while you're iterating on it.

Comment: Don't [modify-a-list-while-iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864393/modify-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `return` statement, so as default the method return `None` you can see it by doing

```
print(reverse([1,2,3,4,5])) # None
```

The first call return `None`, then you call `reverse(None)`, and fail at `len(seq)` because it's `len(None)` indeed

---

This would be the code, but it's doesn't make the reverse of the input

```
def reverse(seq):
    k = len(seq)
    j = k
    for i in range(0, j):
        seq.append(seq.pop(i))
    return seq
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to return a value so that it can be input for another function expecting parameter(s).

Following change will workout for you -

```
def reverse(seq):
    k=len(seq)
    j=k
    for i in range(0,j):
        seq.append(seq.pop(i))
    print(seq)
    return seq

reverse(reverse([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Note: Though not explicitly mentioned, but in case you are trying to reverse the input, your code will not work. It suffers from off-by-1 error.