# Python: Modifying a List of Elements while Iterating

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, iteration

I have the below list:

```
list =[5,10,15,20,25,30]
```

...and I would like to keep the same list but have its elements increased by 5. How could we do this without creating a new list? What kind of loop should I create for this? Is there another way?

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Do not call your list `list` - `list` is a built-in list constructor. (2) You need a `for` loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864393/modify-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another list to the existing list you can use  extend in-build functions.

please refer below link to know more about that:
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/append-extend-python/][1]