# Why "for i in q" makes the result different from "for i in range(len(q))"?

Tags: python, for-loop, breadth-first-search

I have code for calculating max depth using BFS, which works fine, but I couldn't figure out why it fails if I replaced `for i in range(len(q)):` with `for i in q:`.

The code below works correctly and passes all tests:

```
    def maxDepth(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        if not root: return 0
        
        q = list([root])
        level = 0
        while q:
            for i in range(len(q)):
                node = q.pop(0)
                if node.left:
                    q.append(node.left)
                if node.right:
                    q.append(node.right)
            level += 1
        return level
```

But the code below with `for i in q` fails some tests:

```
    def maxDepth(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        if not root: return 0
        
        q = list([root])
        level = 0
        while q:
            for i in q:                     # the only difference
                node = q.pop(0)
                if node.left:
                    q.append(node.left)
                if node.right:
                    q.append(node.right)
            level += 1
        return level
```

`for i in range(len(q)):` and `for i in q:` provide exactly the same number of iterations or do I misunderstand something? I don't understand why it would make any difference... Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`for i in range(len(q)):` and `for i in q:` are not equivalent.

You modify `q` by popping and appending. When you modify a list during iteration, the internal iterator's behavior is undefined (usually skips stuff).

`range(len(q))` checks `q`'s length only once at the start, and from then on the iteration is defined.

Comment: Thank you. So I guess ```for i in q``` changes ```q``` whenever ```q``` changes along ```pop()``` and ```append()```, and it cause the unexpected results.

Comment: @JasonT. That is correct. The iterator (object the `for` loop gained by calling `iter(q)`) runs on the live list (`q`), and takes a new `i` every iteration by index. When you `pop()` you mess up the index, unlike `len(q)` which is evaluated only once at the start.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `q.pop(0)` instruction also plays with `q` which makes your iteration shorter (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13939416/10115198 for a detailed illustration).

It actually doesn't give the same amount of iterations! To get an idea of the problem:

```
q = [1, 2, 3]
for i in q:
    node = q.pop(0)
    print(i, node)
```

gives

```
1 1
3 2
```

but

```
q = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(len(q)):
    node = q.pop(0)
    print(i, node)
```

gives

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed demonstration!

Answer (score 1):

The key difference is that `for i in range(len(q))` creates a new iterator (range) object from q at the time just before the loop. `for i in q` loops over items in q. Your issue is that you are actually modifying `q` from inside your loop with `q.append(...)` and `q.pop(...)`, which can have unexpected behavior as you are seeing.

Simple example -- this will loop forever:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3]
for i in l:
    print(i)
    l.append(999)
```

Comment: Thank you! I never knew ```for i in range(len())``` creates a new iterator. Now I know 