# Modify range variable in for loop (python)

Tags: python, range

I am not sure why python would show this behavior:

```
for x in range(5):
    print "Before: ",x
    if x<3:
        x-=1
    print "After:  ",x
```

I get the output as:

```
Before:  0
After:   -1
Before:  1
After:   0
Before:  2
After:   1
Before:  3
After:   3
Before:  4
After:   4
```

I was not expecting it to change the value of x to 1, after I reduce it to -1 in the first iteration. 
Alternatively, is there a way to achieve the desired behavior when I want to alter the value of range variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what problem you are trying to solve by altering the value of the range variable.

Comment: I think you want a `while` loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scope of python variable in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363138/scope-of-python-variable-in-for-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am not sure why python would show this behavior

Because `x` is reset every iteration of the loop.

If you would like to modify the range, you need to save it to a variable first, and then modify

e.g. in Python2

```
my_range = range(5) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for i,x in enumerate(my_range):
    print "Before: ", my_range[i]
    if x < 3:
        my_range[i] = x-1
    print "After:  ", my_range[i]

print my_range # [-1, 0, 1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: this will not work in python 3.6. it throw TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment error

Comment: `list(range(5))` should be clear to anyone who knows the differences

Answer (score 4):

A `for` loop in Python doesn't care about the current value of `x` (unlike most C-like languages) when it starts the next iteration; it just remembers the current position in the range and assigns the next value. In order to be able to manipulate the loop variable, you need to use a `while` loop, which doesn't exert any control over any variables (it just evaluates the condition you give it).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the while loop approach? My for-loop answer worked fine

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range(5):
```

is the same as:

```
for x in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
```

in each cycle iteration **x** get a new value from the list, it can't be used as C, C#, Java, javascript, ... usual **for**, I agree with @aasmund-eldhuset that a **while** loop will do better what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.6 this will work

```
my_range = list(range(5)) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for i,x in enumerate(my_range):
    print ("Before: ", my_range[i])
    if x < 3:
       my_range[i] = x-1
    print ("After:  ", my_range[i])

print (my_range)
```

You will get out as

```
Before:  0
After:   -1
Before:  1
After:   0
Before:  2
After:   1
Before:  3
After:   3
Before:  4
After:   4
[-1, 0, 1, 3, 4]
```