# Changing the iterator of the for loop inside the code block

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

Suppose I have a code block like,

```
for i in range(15):
    print(i)
    i+=5
```

I expect the i value at each iteration should be i = 0,5,10, ....

Even though I am changing the iterator inside the code block of for loop, the value is not affecting the loop.

Can anyone explain the functionality happening inside?

Comment: [Changing the value of range during iteration in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38672963). Or [Modify range variable in for loop (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36051434)

Comment: Why would it? The range object doesn't know that the variable was changed, it can't return a next value that depends on it.

Comment: A new value is assigned to `i` by the `for` statement at the start of each iteration.  You can monkey with `i` inside the loop, but it'll always get reset to the next value from the iterator.

Comment: To get your desired result: `for i in range(0, 15, 5): print(i)`

Comment: I think the OP wants the first 15 multiples of 5, not the multiples of 5 less than 15.

Comment: Possibly. `for i in range(15): print(i * 5)`

Comment: If you thought that each iteration would add 1 to `i`, then shouldn't the result be `0, 6, 12, ...`? `i+=5` adds 5, then `for` would add 1 more to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you're defining `i` as a number from `0` to `14` everytime it runs the new loop. I think that what you want is this:

```
i = 0
for _ in range(/*how many times you want i to print out*/):
    print(i)
    i += 5
```

Comment: This will go past 15.

Comment: I *know*. Thats on purpose because he wants it fifteen times

Comment: It's not clear what he wants, or what he's thinking the logic is.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop is like an assignment statement. `i` gets a new value assigned at the top of each iteration, no matter what you might do to `i` in the body of the loop.

The `for` loop is equivalent to

```
r = iter(range(15))
while True:
    try:
        i = next(r)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(i)
    i += 5
```

Adding 5 to `i` doesn't have any lasting effect, because `i = next(r)` will always be executed next.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, `range` emits the number and your assignment doesn't matter.

To get the desired result use something like

```
for i in range(0, 15, 5):
    print(i)
```