# Comparable code to array[++i] and array[i++] in Python?

Tags: python, c++, c

In C, as well as in C++, one can in a for-loop change the index (for example `i`). This can be useful to, for example, compare a current element and based on that comparison compare the next element:

```
for(int i = 0; i < end; i++)
  if(array[i] == ':')
    if(array[++i] == ')')
      smileyDetected = true;
```

Now I know this cannot be done in Python (for [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python) [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363138/scope-of-python-variable-in-for-loop)). However, I cannot help wondering if there are short alternatives for Python? I can come up with:

```
while i < end:
    if array[i] == ':':
        i += 1
        if array[i] == ')':
            smileyDetected = True;
```

However, this costs me an extra line, which doesn't sound so bad until you do the same multiple times ('less readable' did not mean having a long file). So to have it in one line, I would think of something like 
`array[i += 1]`, but this is invalid syntax as it seems.

Is there Python equivalent which does the incrementation of the index in the same line as reading out that incremented index?

EDIT:
As most answers mention using `in` to find a substring, as an alternative for the particular example, let me add another example which wouldn't be solvable in such a way:

```
j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < end; i++)
  if(array[i] == ':')
    if(array[++i] == ')')
      anotherArray[j++] = array[++i];
```

With that I mean it's about the incrementing of the index, not the finding of a particular string.

Comment: Why don't you iterate the string in *pairs* of characters?

Comment: The C/C++ will show undefined behavior if the array is no C-string and ':' is the last character.

Comment: If `array` is a string you could just write `smiley_detected = ':)' in array`.

Comment: SImplify like this (non-pythonic way and langauge agnostic)

while i < end:
    if array[i] == ':' and array[i+1]==')':
        smileyDetected = True
    i += 1

Comment: @DieterLücking Not if `end` is smaller than the last index of `array` ;)
@jonrsharpe I want to find what's after the smiley, not if the smiley is there.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
smileyDetected = ':)' in "".join(array)
```

or per @jonrsharpe:

```
from itertools import tee

# pairwise() from "Itertools Recipes"

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

for a, b in pairwise(array):
    if a == ':' and b == ')':
         smileyDetected = True
```

Comment: The first one is wrong with `array = ['foo:', ')bar']`

Comment: Please don't `import *`.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz your example doesn't match OP's example code but my first solution does in fact handle it correctly.  Better posted as a follow up comment to jonrsharpe's pairwise commet to OP.

Comment: @cdlane oh sorry, I misunderstood the question (I thought it was an array of strings instead of an array of chars)

Answer (score 1):

If `array` is a string, the shortest pythonic version would obviously be:

```py
smileyDetected = ':)' in array
```

A more generic / non-string-specific way of doing this would be using iterators:

```py
smileyDetected = (':', ')') in zip(array, array[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

In this special case, you could do:

```
for i, char in enumerate(array[:-1]):
    if char == ":" and array[i+1] == ")":
        smiley_detected = True
```

However, in the more general case, if you need to skip elements, you could modify the raw iterator:

```
iterator = iter(array)
for char in iterator:
    if char == ":" and next(iterator) == ")":
        smiley_detected = True
```

Here you need to take more care about the array bounds; if the last element is `:`, you will get a `StopIteration` exception from calling `next` on the depleted iterator. You would need to catch that.

Comment: The second one is wrong for `array = ['a', ':', ')', 'b']`, because it calls next() twice on the **same** iterator every loop.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz No, it only calls next twice when the current element is ``:``, as the ``and`` operator is short-circuiting. For the given search pattern this works, because it cannot start with ``)``, thus it does not matter if ``)`` is skipped.