# Python 3: replacing elements that passes equality checks and calls another function to validate

Tags: python

Firstly, I am very very new to Python. I understand the basics of for loops 
used to iterate through a list, however, I am trying to replace an element 
that passes a basic equality check, which is this case`== " "`. When the 
iteration reaches a `" "`, it should replace the blank spot with a letter `"A"` 
and return a `True`.

However, this is not the case, it always returns a `False` :(
If someone could find the time to point a very basic way to do this, it 
would be much appreciated. I have searched, but most of the answers include 
such things as `enumerate` and `len` functions etc, which is above my 
understanding thus far. Thank you for any assistance offered.

```
# my list to iterate through.
myList = ["A", "A", " ", "B", "B", "C", " ", "A", "B"]

# my function to check for conditionals
def checkBook(spots,grade):
    if spots[0] == grade and spots[1] == grade and spots[2] == grade:
        return True
    else:
        return False 

# my function to iterate through myList, then calls up the checkBook 
# function to get a return
def compareElements():
    for elements in myList:
        if elements == " ":
            elements = "A"
            print (checkBook(myList, "A"))

compareElements()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363138/scope-of-python-variable-in-for-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
for elements in myList:
    if elements == " ":
        elements = "A"
```

In this case, you are only assigning `"A"` to the variable `elements`, and not modifying the original `myList`.

In this code below, `myList[i] = "A"` will modify `myList`, where `i` is the index of `element`, as `enumerate` will return the index and the item as you iterate through. (changed the variable name from `elements` to `element` to prevent confusion)

```
# my list to iterate through.
myList = ["A", "A", " ", "B", "B", "C", " ", "A", "B"]

# my function to check for conditionals
def checkBook(spots,grade):
    # if spots[0] == grade and spots[1] == grade and spots[2] == grade:
    if spots[0] == spots[1] == spots[2] == grade: # can be simplified to this
        return True
    else:
        return False 

# my function to iterate through myList, then calls up the checkBook 
# function to get a return
def compareElements():
    for i,element in enumerate(myList): # index, item
        if element == " ": 
            myList[i] = "A" # modifies myList
            print (checkBook(myList, "A"))

compareElements() # prints True, True
print(myList) # ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B']
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your time, really great thorough explanation! While I have not learnt the use of enumerate yet, after some digging, I realize it's a much more tidy and easier way to utilize the "for..range" loop. I understand where my mistake was now, I did not modify myList as you suggested. Again, thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
myList = ["A", "A", " ", "B", "B", "C", " ", "A", "B"]
def checkBook(spots,grade):
     new_list = [grade if i == ' ' else i for i in spots]
     return new_list == myList, new_list

flag, final_list = checkBook(myList, "A")
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, however, this is probably above my current understanding of Python. Through scouring the Internet, I'm going to assume you utilized List Comprehension?

Comment: @AmyK Yes, list comprehension is utilized on line 3.