# Unexpected output while using for loop in python

Tags: python-3.6

```
name='ABCDE'
length=len(name)

for i in range(0,length):
    print(name[i],'\t',end='')
    print(i, '\t', end='')
    i+=1
    print(i,'\t',end='')
    print('hello')

Output:
A   0   1   hello
B   1   2   hello
C   2   3   hello
D   3   4   hello
E   4   5   hello
```

I am not able to understand the second line of output.
In the second iteration the value of i should again be incremented in the for loop and the output should be:

```
C  2  3  hello
```

and so on in other iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're assuming the

```
i+=1
```

will effect `i` for the next iteration.

The syntax `for i in range():` in python means that at the beginning of each iteration cycle, `i` will take on the next value provided by `range()`, regardless of an assignment within the body.

In your case, you have

```
range(0, length)
```

Which evaluates to:

```
range(0,5) # == [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Thus `i` takes on the values `0` through `4`.

To convince yourself, try this:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    print(i)
    i = 1000 # any number
```

which prints:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

See [Scope of python variable in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363138/scope-of-python-variable-in-for-loop)