# Go back to specific number in a for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
def five_numbers():
    my_list = []
    for i in range(1, 6):
        user_nr = check_if_number_is_1_to_25(input("Number " + str(i) + ": "))
        my_list.append(user_nr)
    return my_list

def check_if_number_is_1_to_25(number):
    if number.isalpha():
        print("Enter a number between 1 and 25.")
        # Here I want to go back to five_numbers() and the number x (for example number 4)
```

Now I want to check if the input contains any letters. If it has, I want to print a message and then I want to go back to the number that the user was on earlier. I've tried to return five_numbers() but then the user will start from the beginning.

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) ... see the accepted answer.

Comment: I think the question is asking how to update the iterator, and I didn't see that in the previous linked question. I think this question is closer to the one the user is asking;  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363138/scope-of-python-variable-in-for-loop

Answer (score 1):

Add a keyword arg for num and default it to `None`:

```
def five_numbers(num=None):
    my_list = []
    if num is None:
        for i in range(1, 6):
            user_nr = check_if_number_is_1_to_25(input("Number " + str(i) + ": "))
            my_list.append(user_nr)
    else:
        # do other stuff with num (4) here...
    return my_list

def check_if_number_is_1_to_25(number):
    if number.isalpha():
        print("Enter a number between 1 and 25.")
        five_numbers(4)
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why are you typing five_numbers(4) ? I want it to be as a counter. For example, if the user is on number 2, and is typing alpha - I want to go back to the input("Number 2: ")

Comment: @Gringo in that case, you could set a global variable outside all the functions and track that between the functions as it changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop to keep asking the user for a valid input until the user enters one. You should also make the check function raise an exception instead so the caller can catch the exception and retry the input:

```
def five_numbers():
    my_list = []
    for i in range(1, 6):
        while True:
            user_nr = input("Number " + str(i) + ": ")
            try:
                check_if_number_is_1_to_25(user_nr)
                break
            except ValueError as e:
                print(str(e))
        my_list.append(user_nr)
    return my_list

def check_if_number_is_1_to_25(number):
    if number.isalpha():
        raise ValueError('Enter a number between 1 and 25.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a for loop, use a while loop with the list length as its condition. Make the *check* function return a boolean and use it to decide whether to append to the list.

```
def five_numbers():
    my_list = []
    while len(my_list) < 5:
        user_nr = input("Number {}: ".format(len(my_list)+1))
        if check_if_number_is_1_to_25(user_nr):
            my_list.append(user_nr)
        else:
            print("Enter a number between 1 and 25.")
    return my_list

def check_if_number_is_1_to_25(number):
    return number.isdigit() and (1 <= float(number) <= 25)
```