# for loop with changed iterator

Tags: python-3.x

I can't make the iterator shorter while I'm running on it.

I want to write a function which gets a string and deletes repeating sequences in it.
for example:
if a have the string `aaaaabbbbbbbcccccccDDDDDDaaaaa`
I should get in return `abcDa`.

I tried to run over the string with a `for` loop and every time I see a new letter I will save the letter in a variable which adds up to be the fixed string.

```py
def string_sequence_fixing(string):
    c = ''
    for char in my_str:
        if c != char:
            c = char
        else:
            my_str = my_str.replace(c, '', my_str.count(c) - 1)
    return my_str
```

The problem I want to avoid is too many iterations.
When I see a new character I want to delete all the other sequences of it,
but the second line from the end does not update the "condition" in the for a loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scope of python variable in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363138/scope-of-python-variable-in-for-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: loops don't work that way.
Longer answer:
Here is some simple pseudo code, for your perusal:
`j=99
print "J is " j
for j=0;20;5
print j \t
end
print "Now J is " j`

The output may surprise you.
`run
J is 99
0  5  10  15 20
Now J is 99`

The reason is: the variable j in the loop is NOT the as the j variable outside the loop.
I like to use the term "stack" (some languages claim they don't use a stack. In those cases I call it a "not-stack stack). The stack simple means a temporary storage space in memory.
The initial variable "j" goes into the "program data space". The loop variable "j" goes into the "stack data space."

Using a variable doesn't 'really' mean you are using a variable, it's just a mnemonic to a memory space. Let's have another look at that sample code:
`pointer-to-program-space-variable-named-j = 99    (poke into memory location 1:4500)
pointer-to-stack-space-variable-named-j = 0        (poke into memory location 87:300)
print pointer-to-stack-space-variable-named-j followed by tab
increment pointer-to-stack-space-variable-named-j by 5
repeat until pointer-to-stack-space-variable-named-j = 20
print pointer-to-program-space-variable-named-j`

With this knowledge, let's look at your code to see what is going on:
`def string_sequence_fixing(string):
    c = ''
    for char in *STACK*.my_str:
        if c != char:
            c = char
        else:
            my_str = my_str.replace(c, '', *PROGRAM*.my_str.count(c) - 1)
    return my_str`

See how they are different variables? NEVER assume that a loop variable and a program variable are the same. You need to redo you algorithm to accomplish what you want to do.

Also, see the link provided by @David Cullen.

Comment: So you say that the variable that i use in the loop is some kind of a temporary variable copied from the original `my_str`.

So how can I change the original `my_str`?

Comment: I'm not a C guy. My suggestion would be something like this:<br/>
        else:
            my_return_str = my_str.replace(c, '', my_str.count(c) - 1)
    return my_return_str
This way, you are not changing the value you are looping on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupby()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). Code is like:

```py
data = 'aaabbbcccDDDDDEfggghiij'

from itertools import groupby
dataN = ''
for d in groupby(data):
    dataN += d[0]

print(dataN)
```

output:

```py
abcDEfghij
```