# Why do i need a new variable in the while loop of this implementation of Insertionsort?

Tags: python, insertion-sort

I have an implementation of the Insertionsort algorithm where in the lecture there is a new instance variable before the while loop.

```
def swap(l, i, j):
    temp = l[i]
    l[i] = l[j]
    l[j] = temp


def ins_sort(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        j = i
        while j > 0 and l[j - 1] > l[j]:
            swap(l, j - 1, j)
            j = j - 1


    return l
```

In my testing and playing around the algorithm worked without it as well though and I do not understand why I would need to write an extra line of code if it is not necessary.

```
def swap(l, i, j):
    temp = l[i]
    l[i] = l[j]
    l[j] = temp


def ins_sort(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        while i > 0 and l[i - 1] > l[i]:
            swap(l, i - 1, i)
            i = i - 1


    return l
```

Comment: The `swap` function is also unnecessary with the temporary value. `l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]` should do the same

Comment: Looks like the author doesn't know Python.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the original code is a translation from the c/c++ implementation where modifying i inside the loop would be persistent and affect the loop itself. However since in python, i will be reset each iteration, the second code will also work.
In short I don't think that line is necessary for a python implementation.

ref:[Scope of python variable in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363138/scope-of-python-variable-in-for-loop)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the reference and clearing that up for me

Answer (score -1):

You could also try the following program for Insertion sort where the use of the extra variable is not necessary:

```
l=[4,3,1,2]
for i in range(1,len(l)): 
      key=l[i]  
      for j in range(i-1,-1,-1):
          if l[j]>key:
              l[j+1]=l[j]
          else:
              j=j+1
              break

      l[j]=key

print(l)
```