# Modify item using IN versus Indexing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I'm trying to modify item in a list using IN and Indexing. While modifying via indexing, the item was actually changed. However, when I try to change via IN keyword, it seems that the item in the list does not change.

- What's the difference between both method internally?
- When using IN, does it mean that you iterate through the list and assign the value of each item in the variable in for statement?

```
lines = ['hi', 'hello']

for line in lines:
    line += '*'

for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] += '#'

print(lines)
```

```
Output:
['hi#', 'hello#']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scope of python variable in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363138/scope-of-python-variable-in-for-loop)

Comment: You can't mutate immutable types in python.

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop, 'line' is merely a placeholder for value received from lines in each iteration.

Whereas, in the second loop, you're directly referring to the individual elements in the list using their index

```
lines = ['hi', 'hello']

print(f"Outside the loop - id(lines): {id(lines)}\n")

for line in lines:
    line += '*'
    print(f"id(line): {id(line)}")
print("\n")
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] += '#'
    print(f"id(lines[{i}]: {id(lines[i])}")
    
    
print(f"\n\nid(lines): {id(lines)},id(lines[0]): {id(lines[0])}, id(lines[1]): {id(lines[1])}\n")
print(lines)
```

Look at the output. You'll notice that id of 'line' is same throughout the loop and it's different from lines[0] and lines[1]. That means, line and lines[0] are not the same and they're located at different locations in the memory.

OUTPUT:

```
Outside the loop - id(lines): 2831707232384

id(line): 2831707722928
id(line): 2831707722928


id(lines[0]: 2831707976816
id(lines[1]: 2831707977456


id(lines): 2831707232384,id(lines[0]): 2831707976816, id(lines[1]): 2831707977456

['hi#', 'hello#']
```

Comment: Sorry, I posted a similar idea in my answer at almost the same time. I think they are different enough to both be relevant.

Comment: Glad you did. I learnt a few things from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way is to create a new list and don't try to change elements of a `list` inplace

```
lines = ['hi', 'hello']
print([f'{line}#' for line in lines])
```

Output

```
['hi#', 'hello#']
```

Both loops can't change a string. They are immutable in python. Your second loop is assigning a new reference to a new string to the given index.

We can verify that by comparing the `id` of the strings

```
lines = ['hi', 'hello']

print(*map(id, lines))
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] += '#'
print(*map(id, lines))

print(lines)
```

Output

```
139964185810032 139963627798960
139963551752432 139963317214640
['hi#', 'hello#']
```

Mutable types (for example a `list`) behave differently

```
lines = ['hi', 'hello']

lines = [[*i] for i in lines] # convert strings to mutable lists

print(*map(id, lines))
for line in lines:
    line += ['#']
print(*map(id, lines))

lines = [''.join(i) for i in lines] # convert lists to immutable strings
print(lines)
```

Output

```
139963318712752 139963316794224
139963318712752 139963316794224
['hi#', 'hello#']
```