# How to increment the iterating variable within a for loop python

Tags: python

I'm trying to increment a for loop within itself if a certain condition is met, as shown in the code below

```
for i in range(0,5):
   if condition == True:
      i+=1
   print(i)
```

If it runs as I want it to, the output should be: "1 3 5". Instead, the output is "0 1 2 3 4". Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It's hard to see how you are getting this output unless `condition` is never True. It's always helpful to create an example that people can actually run.

Comment: [Why doesn't modifying the iteration variable affect subsequent iterations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363138/)

Comment: Depending on what exactly your trying to do, you also might be able to use the `continue` statement when the condition is `False`. Otherwise `while` is the way to go as others have already stated

Comment: If you enter or paste the code into [link](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) you can see the code executing ad you step through which explains what is happening. This is a very useful approach for such code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do with a `while` loop what the `for` was doing for you.

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
   if condition == True:
      i+=1
   print(i)
   i += 1
```

When you do `for i in xxx:`, the `xxx` is constructed before the loop ever runs.  It is going to feed new values to `i` regardless of what happens inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip iterator elements by creating and controlling the iterator yourself ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3K5Pz81IySzLz8xRsFUKKSlO5uDJLgMzMktQijaLEvPRUDQMdU01NrrT8IoVMhcw8oIwVl4KCQmaaApJWiF6wBEhO29YQysxLrSjRyCzRUfDLz0vVBAkWFGXmAYU0IQ6AugPmHgA)):

```py
condition = True

it = iter(range(0,5))
for i in it:
   if condition == True:
      i+=1
      next(it, None)
   print(i)
```

Though you might be better off with a `while` loop.

Answer (score -3):

Like Tim was mentioning, when you're using a for loop, the variable `i` is being 're-generated' at the start of each iteration, regardless of what its value was in the previous iteration. It's sort of a placeholder iterator so trying to replace it and print it's new value won't work. You could work with the iterators current value by doing something like:

```py
for i in range(0,3):
   if condition == True:
      print(i+1)
```

Essentially, would have to use a `while` loop if you were intending to actually store or be able to modify the previous state of the variable `i`