# Can't modify list elements in a loop

Tags: python, list, loops

While looping over a list in Python, I was unable to modify the elements without a list comprehension.
For reference:

```
li = ["spam", "eggs"]
for i in li:
    i = "foo"

li
["spam", "eggs"]

li = ["foo" for i in li]
li 
["foo", "foo"]
```

So, why can't I modify elements through a loop in Python? There's definitely something I'm missing, but I don't know what. I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find a question about this, and if there is a link, that would be more than enough.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating)

Comment: It is not a duplicate imo. The linked answers do not explain why the loop in the form `for item in list` does not modify items.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Because the way `for i in li` works is something like this:

```
for idx in range(len(li)):
    i = li[idx]
    i = 'foo'
```

So if you assign anything to `i`, it won't affect `li[idx]`.

The solution is either what you have proposed, or looping through the indices:

```
for idx in range(len(li)):
    li[idx] = 'foo'
```

or use `enumerate`:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(li):
    li[idx] = 'foo'
```

Comment: Looping through the indices doesn't seem to be working for me, I'm using python 3.6.  Never mind.  I'm using a slice, that's why.

Answer (score 14):

In fact with list comprehension you are not modifying the list, you are creating a new list and then assigning it to the variable that contained the previous one.

Anyway, when you do `for i in li` you are getting a copy of each value of `li` in variable `i`, you don't get the reference to a position in `li`, so you are not modifying any value in `li`.

If you want to modify your list you can do it with `enumerate`:

```
>>> li = ["spam", "eggs"]
>>> for i,_ in enumerate(li):
        li[i] = "foo"
>>> li
 ['foo', 'foo']
```

or with `xrange` (in Python 2.7, use range in python 3):

```
>>> for i in xrange(len(li)):
        li[i] = "foo"
>>> li 
 ['foo', 'foo']
```

or with the list comprehension you showed in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to modify a list while looping:

```
lst = range(10)  // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
    lst[i] = 0   // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`for element in li` - returns you a copy of element, not the element itself.

Solution for your case would be:

```
for i in range(len(li)):
    li[i] = 'foo'
```

Comment: There are no copies returned.

Comment: Incorrect, no copies are created

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using dictionaries might be helpful.

```
>>> li = {0: "spam", 1:"eggs"}
    for k, v in li.iteritems():
        li[k] = "foo"

>>> li
{0: 'foo', 1: 'foo'}
```