# Why does dropna and as_type etc not work in for loop? Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This a very simple 2 liner code, but I am not able to figure out why it does not work?

```
df_train_data = df_train_data.dropna(subset=['sqft', 'am'])
```

works, but I am not able to figure out why ,

```
   for x in [df_train_data, df_test_data]:
       x = x.dropna(subset=['sqft', 'am'])
```

Does not, stuck with this for 2 hours now.. Can anyone please help to understand why it is not working?

EDIT: 
Same behavior is observed when changing this :

```
   for x in [df_train_data, df_test_data]:
       df_name = df_name[['uuid', 'parcel']].astype(str)
```

Though inplace=True may work, im trying to understand how to change it for all statements like another example i stated for (as_type) etc.

Comment: The linked duplicate explains why it doesn't work, a simple solution to make it work is to change the `dropna` operation to be `inplace`. Change `x = x.dropna(subset=['sqft', 'am'])` to `x.dropna(subset=['sqft', 'am'], inplace=True)`

Comment: but how does it work outside the for loop if it requires inplace=True

Comment: `x` is a reference to the "real" dataframe (`df_train_data` or `df_test_data`) and doing `dropna` inplace will then modify the original dataframe.

Comment: yeah, i get using inplace = True works, but how does it work outside the loop without inplace = True, and there are some statements like : as_type again which dont work when used in for loop but as 2 separate statements it works !

Comment: Your problem is the same as in the duplicate question: `x` is a reference to each element of the list, one at a time, not the element itself, so changing it is like changing a temporary variable and discarding it right away, which will not change the original. It wouldn't matter what function you called, the problem is with `x =`. You can use list comprehension as is the first answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: `x.changeyourself` works (that's what `inplace=True` effectively means) because it goes through the reference to change the referenced object, while `x=` makes the reference point to some other object before discarding it.

Comment: The list comprehension solution in the duplicate question's [answer by @miradulo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41812654/3216427) is a way to receive the modified objects into a new list, which can then replace the old list.