# Why does this code fail? assigning variable to list of itself in for loop

Tags: python, variables, reference, variable-assignment, immutability

```
a = 'hello'
b = None
c = None
for x in [a, b, c]:
    if isinstance(x, (basestring, dict, int, float)) or x is None:
        x = [x]
a
```

returns `'hello'`, but expected `['hello']`. However, this works:

```
a = 'hello'
a = [a]
a
```

returns `['hello']`.

Comment: You are updating the value of `x` but not `a`.

Comment: I have no idea about python, but many languages disallow assigning to the loop variable. It is under the control of the compiler; how do you expect the program to loop properly if you modify its loop variable? That being said, maybe python allows that. Just a possible reason.

Comment: In the first code the result is in ```x``` not in ```a```

Comment: Doh! Coding too late! Thanks for the help

Comment: Python's variables are just labels to values. You are not changing the value you are just pointing the label to a different value. Changing which value `x` points to does not change which value `a` points to. @Aganju python has no issues with changing the loop variable, as it is just reassigned on every loop to the `next()` value in the iteration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't modify list elements in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290762/cant-modify-list-elements-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve that, first you have to understand that you have two diferent refecerences, a and x (for each element), and the reference for the list [a,b,c], used only in the for loop, and never more.

To achieve your goal, you could do this:

```
a = 'hello'
b = None
c = None
lst = [a, b, c] #here I create a reference for a list containing the three references above
for i,x in enumerate(lst):
    if isinstance(x, (str,dict, int, float)) or x is None: #here I used str instead basestring
        lst[i] = [x]

print(lst[0]) #here I print the reference inside the list, that's why the value is now showed modified
```

> ['hello']

but as I said, if you do print(a) it will show again:

> 'hello' #here i printed the value of the variable a, wich has no modification

because you never did anything with it.

Take a look at this question to understand a little more about references [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: 'and a reference never used for the list [a,b,c]' you might want to reword that... the reference to the list is most certainly used during the for loop...

Comment: @shadow ups, my bad :), thanks for pointing me that, very good observation

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys. Marking Damian's answer b/c he also suggested a solution (modifying list elements directly)

Comment: @bamboo77 no problem! I have always loved to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Lets work through this one line at a time;

```
a = 'hello'  # assigns 'hello' to a.
b = None  # etc...
c = None
for x in [a, b, c]:  # Creates list from the values in 'a' 'b' and 'c', then iterates over them.
    # This if statement is always True. x is always either a string, or None.
    if isinstance(x, (basestring, dict, int, float)) or x is None:
        x = [x]  # On the first iteration, sets variable to the expected ['hello']
        # After that though - it replaces it with [None]
a  # = 'hello' - you have not assigned anything to the variable except on the first line.
```

The only variable that is ever set to `['hello']` is `x`, which is quickly overwritten with `None`. If you changed your if check to exclude `or x is None` and assigned to `a` instead of `x` you would get your desired result.

It's also worth noting that the list `[a, b, c]` is created when you start the for loop. Changing `a` `b` or `c` during the for loop will have no effect - the list has already been created.

Comment: Nice work explaining line by line, it's a very nice answer. Plus one

Comment: Yours is nice too - it's clear from our different interpretations of the goal that some more detail is required in the question though ;) +1 returned.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are great. I think, to generalize, the list element is immutable/hashable so the for loop returns a copy, not a reference to the original object. I should've spotted this, but teaches me for coding too long without sleep!

I ended up using this:

```
def lst(x):
    if isinstance(x, (basestring, dict, int, float)) or x is None:
        x = [x]
    return x
[a, b, c] = map(lst, [a, b, c])
```