# For loop won't work through pandas dataframes list

Tags: python

`frames` is a list of pandas dataframes , filled like that

```
frames [df1,df2...dfn]
```

Next I start loop for each element , but nothing happens:

```
for frame in frames:
    frame = frame.apply(lambda col: col.astype(str).str.lower())
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please try to create a [MCVE] - it's difficult to know what is going "wrong" from what you have posted so far.

Comment: Format and formulate your question in a proper manner.

Comment: Please include a full code snippet. Also, describe the format of the dataframes contained in the list.

Comment: Check the accepted answer to [Can't modify list elements in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19290762/2314737) you're not changing the elements of the list in the for loop

Comment: To fix it use: `for i in range(len(frames)):
  frames[i]=frames[i].apply(lambda...`