# two ways of looping over list - difference

Tags: python, list

I have to reverse every word in a list which length is greater that 4. So I tried:

```
for word in words:
    if len(word) >= 5:
        word = word[::-1]
```

and it didn't work. But this:

```
 for i in range(len(words)):
        if len(words[i]) >= 5:
            words[i] = words[i][::-1]
```

works fine. What's the diference?

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate through a list Python creates references (with same ID) to your variable. However these are not editable in place. Check this for instance: [Can't modify list elements in a loop Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290762)

Consider this example which hopefully can help you out:

```
words = ['abcdef','abc']

for ind,i in enumerate(words):
    print('Loop {}'.format(ind))
    i = i[::-1]
    print('words equal {}'.format(words))
    words[ind] = words[ind][::-1] 
    print('words equal {}'.format(words))    
    print()
```

Returns:

```
Loop 0
words equal ['abcdef', 'abc']   # <--- after changing i (nothing changed)
words equal ['fedcba', 'abc']   # <--- after changing words[ind]

Loop 1
words equal ['fedcba', 'abc']   # <--- after changing i (nothing changed)
words equal ['fedcba', 'cba']   # <--- after changing words[ind]
```

---

**in your case**

The most simple solution would be to use a list comprehension. Consider this:

```
rWords = [word[::-1] if len(word) >=5 else word for word in words]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    word = word[::-1]
```

word is not referenced to the words[i].
You can do this with functional programming.

```
new_words = list(word[::-1] if len(word) >= 5 else word for word in words)
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's going on here, compare what happens in a similar example, where I want to set any numbers bigger than 20 to -1:

```
numbers = [1, 10, 30, 40, 50]
for number in numbers:
    if number > 20:
        number = -1
print(numbers) # same as before!
```

Why does this not set the last three numbers to -1? Because `number` here is a value—it's location in memory is totally unrelated to the contents of the `numbers` array. `word` in your example is exactly the same.

Inside your loop, `word` is bound to a new piece of memory whose contents happen to be the same as the current entry of the `words` array. By the time `word` is defined in your first snippet, you have lost any way to manipulate the array location it came from. By iterating over the indexes like in your second snippet, you keep a back door into the array.

These two references,

- http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/ and
- https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/

might help understand the following tricky business: instead of a list of strings, what happens if we have a list of lists?

```
listOfLists = [[1], [2, 3], [9, 10, 11], [40, 50, 60, 70]]
for l in listOfLists:
    if len(l) >= 3:
        l[:] = l[::-1] # note that `[:]`!!!
print(listOfLists)
```

This actually will reverse any sub-list that has more than 2 elements. Can you understand why? If so, take this gold star: !

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is because when you do the first one, you are only modifying the `word` variable, you aren't modifying the `words` list. But when you are using the second example, you are modifying it because you are using `words[i] = words[i][::-1]`. In this example, you are modifying the words list because the `words[i]` is the modifier; you are setting the element of the list into something.