# “Redeclared variable defined above without usage” in python?

Tags: python, variables

It might be idiotic but drives me crazy:
Why this code doesn't work?
Gives me a warning of “Redeclared j variable defined above without usage”
and doesn't rewrites elements.
Thanks.

```
a=[[1,2],[3,4,0],[5,6,0,0]]

for i in a:
    for j in i:
        j=0

print(a)
```

Comment: `j` gets value from `a` but it doesn't keep refrerence to place in this list so `j = 0` doesn't have access to `a`

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Does this answer [address your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

The warning message is trying to tell you just what it says: You *are* technically "redeclaring" a variable.  (Though it's better thought of as a *name*, to which you are re-assigning.)

Specifically, a for-loop is basically an implicit re-assignment of the name `j` to the next `int` in `i`.  Your IDE detects that you don't do anything with that temporary assignment before doing a blanket-`j=0` within each nested for-loop.

You have probably noticed that all of this does not actually modify `a`.  That's because, as pointed out in the comments, [you're not mutating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19290762/7954504) the actual elements (or sub-elements) of `a`.