# Convert all dictionary values into proportions

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have defined a dictionary as

```
coocurences = {('a', 'b'): 74, ('a', 'c'): 33, ('b', 'c'): 26}
```

and I would like to change the values of this dictionary into proportions of the sum of its values:

```
{('a', 'b'): 0,556390977443609‬, ('a', 'c'): 0,2481203007518797, ('b', 'c'): 0,1954887218045113‬‬}
```

I have tried with:

```
for x in coocurences.values():
    x = (x/sum(coocurences.values()))
```

but it tells me: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable.
Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted results in that error? Seems like you would get that error from doing `for x in coocurences.values:` (without the parentheses).

Comment: You are right. I forgot the parentheses in the code. I get no Error when added but also not the anticipated result. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of problems with the code you presented:

1. the code you posted doesn't throw any errors (I think in your actual code you might've had `for x in coocurences.values` without any parentheses, which would throw an error).
2. `x` is only a *copy* of the values in the dictionary. Changing `x` won't change the values in the dict. See [Can't modify list elements in a loop Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290762/cant-modify-list-elements-in-a-loop-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)
   .
3. if you're changing the values during the loop, the sum you compute will also change. It's also less efficient to compute the sum every so you might as well compute it before the loop.

Putting it all together:

```
total = sum(coocurences.values())
for k,v in coocurences.items():
    coocurences[k] = v/total
```

Better yet, use a dict comprehension:

```
total = sum(coocurences.values())
answer = {k: v/total for k,v in coocurences.items()}
```

Comment: would there be a way to make this dictionary a list like (('a', 'b', 0.556390977443609‬), ...)?

Comment: @JohannesJamrosz `answer = [k+(v/total,) for k,v in coocurences.items()]`. I'd recommend you learn more about list comprehensions. You can pretty much transform you're data however you want with them. Not only is it very pythonic, but it also is more efficient and uses less lines of code.

Comment: grandiose. Thanks alot. I will do so.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this. Rather then using ".values()" you can use the key to change the value, if that makes sense.

```
    for x in coocurences:
        coocurences[x] = (coocurences[x]/sum([coocurences[i] for i in coocurences]))
```

Comment: That won't work, since the sum would change each time since you're changing the values at each iteration.

Comment: You could do this with a running mean

Comment: So update your answer with https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106720/717436 and you are good to go!

Comment: @JayMody This online approach is perfectly suitable (if not perhaps efficient etc?)

Comment: @jtlz2 That is a valid approach, but I'm only commenting on the fact that the answer given here is simply incorrect.