# Trying to convert strings in list to dates in Python

Tags: python, datetime

```
import datetime as dt
current_dates = ['09 May 2020', '10 May 2020', '11 May 2020', '15 May 2020']

for item in current_dates:
    date = item
    date = dt.datetime.strptime(item, '%d %b %Y')
    item = date
    print(current_dates)
```

I'm trying to convert the items in the `current_dates` list to datetime, but when I subsequently type `type(current_dates[0]` the program returns `str`

Comment: Use list comprehension: `[dt.datetime.strptime(item, '%d %b %Y') for item in current_dates]`.

Comment: the reason why the type in `current_dates` is not changed is because it's not mutated nor re-declared. You just iterate it in for loop. Either use a new variable to store the new datetime objects or use list comprehension as proposed above.

Comment: When you iterate through a list you use a copy of each element, not the reference of the same element in the list. So you have to reassign the values once computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the new datetime values to the list

```
import datetime as dt
current_dates = ['09 May 2020', '10 May 2020', '11 May 2020', '15 May 2020']

current_dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(item, '%d %b %Y') for item in current_dates]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290762/cant-modify-list-elements-in-a-loop-python