# For loop - filter multiple dataframes - rows/columns

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Hello Pythoners and Pythonistas,

I am trying to filter multiple dataframes based on a list of names. I wrote this code, but I am not sure why is not working.

```
df1= {"Name" :["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"],
      "X":[30,40,50,60],
      "Y":[20,30,10,40],
      "Z":[10,20,20,10]}

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
name_lists = ['name1','name2','name3','name5'] 
for dataframe in dfs:
      dataframe = dataframe[dataframe["ColumnName"].isin(name_lists)]
```

Any suggestion is more than welcomed.
Thank you,
Qtry

Comment: You're creating a new variable `dataframe` in each iteration of the loop, not modifying the existing values in the list dfs. Accessing by index would work `dfs[0] = ...` for example.

Comment: What would be the output?

Comment: thanks both. @HenryEcker so the code will look something like: `dfs[0]= dataframe[dataframe["ColumnName"].isin(name_lists)]`

Comment: @DaniMesejo my output will be a new dataframe containing only the values in the list

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19290848/15497888) for a complete example of modifying list elements in a for loop. Just replace `li` with your list `dfs`.

Comment: that's not what I need or I don't know how to apply that logic. Thanks anyway.