# how to drop level 0 in two dataframes using for loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

week and month are both dataframes, filtered from a Master based on based on month and week values  like week 18 and "May"
I have run pivot_table function on them, after which I want to rename level 1 column names and then drop the level 0 column names. both the dataframes week and month have gone through same operation
the statement `df = df.droplevel(0,axis=1)` does not change the df in anyway, what m I doing wrong

```
for df in (week, month):
        
df.columns.set_levels(['a','b','c','d'],level=1,inplace=True)
        
df = df.droplevel(0,axis=1)
```

Comment: Could you add a self-contained example that reproduces your problem (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/14311263))?

Comment: You can't change a dataframe in a for loop like that, as you are actually just changing variable `df` each time, not `week` and `month`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290762/cant-modify-list-elements-in-a-loop/19290848#19290848  There are definitely ways of doing this, but do you need to do this in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a dataframe in a for loop like that, as you are actually just changing variable `df` each time, not `week` and `month`: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290762/cant-modify-list-elements-in-a-loop/19290848#19290848).  There are definitely ways of doing this, but do you need to do this in a loop?

Here is one way of completing this (I have changed `df` to `x`, and changed your list of dataframes to list of variable names as strings), by using [`globals()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-globals-function/?msclkid=baaac7c3cef311ec964c003b878ccc07):

```
for x in ["week", "month"]:
    globals()[x].columns.set_levels(['a','b','c','d'],level=1,inplace=True)
    globals()[x] = globals()[x].droplevel(0,axis=1)
```