# How to edit the elements of a 2d array and display the edited 2d array?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

May I know how do i edit a constant 2D array variable upon meeting certain conditions and then save into the variable for processing later ? 
Currently, with the code below, I was unable to store my data in userInput into the column variable.

When i print BOARD, the values are still unchanged ! How will i be able to traverse the 2D array as shown below and edit certain elements and save them back into the variable BOARD?

The source code is below :

```
for row in BOARD:

    if userInput not in row:
        userInput = raw_input ("Please enter a character into the program")
    if userInput in row:
        for column in row:
            if userInput != column:
                print column
                print userInput
                column = userInput
                break
```

Comment: Related: [How to modify list entries during for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store them back with their corresponding indices, which are got with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function, like this

```
for i, row in enumerate(BOARD):
    ...
    ...
    for j, column in enumerate(row):
        ...
        BOARD[i][j] = userInput
        ...
```

In this case, since you are altering the `row`, you can drop the outer `enumerate`, like [Ashwini Chaudhary suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326421/how-to-edit-the-elements-of-a-2d-array-and-display-the-edited-2d-array/26326448?noredirect=1#comment41317054_26326448)

```
for row in BOARD:
    ...
    ...
    for i, column in enumerate(row):
        ...
        row[i] = userInput
        ...
```

Comment: I think we can drop the outer enumerate call since `row` is simply a reference to the inner list and use `row[j] = ...`

Comment: works like a charm ! absolutely brillant ! thanks mate !

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks man, I included your suggestion in the answer :-)