# Python - Comparing 2 floats

Tags: python, compare

I have the following list:

```
[0.12458333333051996, 0.7976157407465507, 0.4842939814843703, 0.9736921296280343, 0.4590740740750334, 0.48178240740526235, 0.46826388888439396, 0.0013078703705105, 0.4625000000014552, 0.4758796296300716, 0.4797685185185401, 6.87130787037313, 0.49761574074364034, 2.9876041666648234, 0.4683564814768033, 0.45549768517958, 0.43494212962832535, 2.030381944445253, 0.48494212963123573, 0.817592592597066]
```

I run this code on the list above:

```
for dt in dtime_list:
    if dt > 0.00694444444444444:
        dtime_list.remove(dt)

print(dtime_list)
```

Output:

```
==>[0.7976157407465507, 0.9736921296280343, 0.48178240740526235, 0.0013078703705105, 0.4758796296300716, 6.87130787037313, 2.9876041666648234, 0.45549768517958, 2.030381944445253, 0.817592592597066]
```

I was expecting there wouldn't remain a float greater than 0.00694444444444444. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

My array is actually float values read from excel for time, with if "dt > 0.00694444444444444" I am trying to find the values greater than 10 mins and remove them from the list.

Comment: You should never modify a list while iterating over it. Start with a new empty list, and copy only those items you want.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should not modify a list while you are iterating over it. Creating a new list containing only the elements that satisfy the criterion you want is easy with a list comprehension:

```
cutoff = 0.00694444444444444
filtered_list = [ dt for dt in dtime_list if dt <= cutoff ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very very bad idea to remove item within a while (or a for).
Best make a new list!
    nv_lst = []
    for dt in dtime_list:
        if dt <= 0.00694444444444444:
            nv_lst.append(dt)
    print(nv_lst)