# A basic python function to censor replace words in sentences

Tags: python

I am trying to build a simple function to censor a specific word in a sentence. For example `"hello hello hi"` to `"***** ***** hi"` if I feed `censor("hello hello hi", "hello")`. Assuming I will not receive punctuation and sentences with upper case letters or empty strings.

After researching online I understand there is simpler solution, for example:

```
def censor(text, word):
    return text.replace(word, "*" * len(word))
```

I still want to understand from a learning perspective, what I did wrong in the below more complicated code.

```
def censor(text,word):
    split_text = text.split()
    length = len(word)
    for item in split_text:
        if item == word:
            item = ("*" * length)
        else:
            item = item
    return " ".join(split_text)
```

Comment: Does the code not work? Or else why do you assume you did something "wrong"?

Comment: You are not updating the values in `split_text` at all. Basically  `lst = [0, 1]; a = lst[0]; a = 2` won't affect `lst`.

Comment: I am doing this on a codecademy course, the virtual machine gave this error:

**Oops, try again. Your function fails on censor("hey hey hey","hey"). It returns "hey hey hey" when it should return "*** *** ***".

Comment: Changing `item` doesn't change `split_test`. Your code is simply splitting the text and then joining it back together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably see *what* you did wrong based on the comments. But you might not understand *why* (and based on your question I think you may be interested to know).

In python you can roughly divide the datatypes into 2 categories: mutable and immutable. The basic difference is that you can create **references** to mutable type variables whereas you can only pass around the **values** of immutable type variables. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types-python) for examples.

In your case you are iterating through a list containing strings. Strings happen to be immutable. So when you change `item` it won't have any effect on the corresponding element in `split_text`.

If instead you were iterating through a list of lists, you would actually be able to change the list elements using the placeholder variable.

Illustrated with an example:

```
x = [["foo"],["foo","bar"]]
for i in x:
    if len(i) == 1:
        i[0] += "bar"
    else:
        i.append("foobar")
print(x) #[["foobar"],["foo","bar","foobar"]]
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: OMG this is amazing. I was a bit aware of this difference unconsciously but the online course didn't really mention it - probably too conceptual for an entry course. But now as you point it out it explains some of the mistakes I made in other exercises too.

Just one question - how do you identify mutable vs immutable datatypes when you code? are there any rule of thumbs or simply memorisation?

Thank you.

Comment: Without getting too abstract, things which are dynamically sized will probably be mutable. Numbers, booleans, and strings will be immutable. refer to [this wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types#Mutable_vs_Immutable_Objects) for examples. If you are interested in a more abstract/philosophical analysis on what types should be immutable vs. mutable you shouuld check out a book on OOP design ideologies! :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution I came up with was a little simpler and gets the job done.

1.I make sure both arguments are a string and then check if the word is in the text string. 
2.Then if the word is in the text string I get the length of the word.
3.Then I replace the word inside the string with * however many times the word is long.

```
def censor(text,word):
t=str(text)
w=str(word)
if w in t:
    l=len(w)
    item = ("*" * l)
    return t.replace(w,item)
else:
    return t
```

Answer (score 1):

The for-loop in your code does not reference or modify the actual item in `split_text`. Try this:

```
for item in range(len(split_text)):
        if item == word:
            split_text[item] = ("*" * length)
            ...
```

Also, it is generally considered poor practice to modify a list within a loop. See this post: [How to modify list entries during for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned other answers, you can't change list value in for loop.

You can access list value using `enumerate`, get index of value. And, you don't need `else` because you don't change value.

```
for idx, item in enumerate(split_text):
    if item == word:
        split_text[idx] = ("*" * length)
```

Comment: Thanks, enumerate was one of the early functions I learnt from the course but never really practised. This answer is clean yet utilises beginner knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the variable and the value that the variable has at a given point at the running time. The statement

```
for item in split_text:
```

Sequentially assigns the value of each item in `split_text` to `item`.

```
item = ("*" * length)
```

Changes `item` to a new value computed from its length. But `split_text` remains exactly what it was at the beginning.