# Fastest way to modify list values with condition python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to know if there's a way in python to do something like that:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]

for e in a:

    print e+=[100 if e<4 else 1]
```

This should print the numbers:
101,102,103,5,6

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List comprehension is one way:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

b = [x+100 if x < 4 else x+1 for x in a]

[100, 102, 103, 5, 6]
```

Or as [thefourtheye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903116/thefourtheye) suggested:

```
b = [x + (100 if x < 4 else 1) for x in a]
```

Now, as to your code, this is the fix:

```
for e in a:
    print e+(100 if e<4 else 1)
```

You can also do it with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map):

```
>>> map(lambda s: s+(100 if s < 4 else 1), a)
[101, 102, 103, 5, 6]
```

Remember if you were in Python3, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map) returns a generator, so you have to `list` it:

```
>>> list(map(lambda s: s+(100 if s < 4 else 1), a))
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify the list [**in place**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4082739/355230), you'd need to do something like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i, e in enumerate(a):
    a[i] += 100 if e < 4 else 1

print(a)  # -> [101, 102, 103, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
 >>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [x+100 if x < 4 else x+1 for x in a]
>>> print b
[101, 102, 103, 5, 6]
>>>
```