# Python: strange issue where conditionally removing elements from a list

Tags: python, string, list

(*I see that this question is a duplicate. Sorry everybody, I wasn't sure of the wording so I couldn't find the other question*)

I define the following list of strings:

```
x=["foo_a","foo_a_b","foo"]
```

then I do the following:

```
for i in x:
    if (("a" not in i) or ("b" in i)):
        x.remove(i)
```

and I get

```
In [92]: x
Out[92]: ['foo_a', 'foo']
```

I would expect the element "foo" to be removed too, because it doesn't contain "a" and so it doesn't verify the first condition.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should not modify a list while iterating through it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop.

Comment: So the output you want is this? `['foo_a', 'foo_a_b']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are modifying the list you are iterating on**. Iterate over a copy of `x`:

```
x=["foo_a","foo_a_b","foo"]
for i in list(x):
    if (("a" not in i) or ("b" in i)):
        x.remove(i)
```

Or even better, avoid using a `for` loop and create a new list with a list comprehension and assign it to `x`

```
x = ["foo_a","foo_a_b","foo"]
x = [item for item in x if not (("a" not in i) or ("b" in i))]
```