# python - How to modify a string in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, function

I want to make a function that adds a specific word in front of every string in the array. At the end I want the array changed. I have this code:

```
def make_great(magicians):
    """Change magicians"""
    for magician in magicians:
        magician = "the Great" + magician


magicians = ["hudini", "angel", "teller", "anderson", "copperfield"]
make_great(magicians)
print(magicians)
```

This code doesn't change the array. How can I make my function work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to loop over the list with both the index and the value, then use the index to change the value directly into the list:

```
def make_great(magicians):
    for index, magician in enumerate(magicians):
        magicians[index] = "the Great " + magician
```

Answer (score 6):

When you use a for-each loop:

```
def make_great(magicians):    
    for magician in magicians:
        magician = "The Great" + magician
```

you're actually creating a new string magician; so modifying it won't modify the original array as you found.

Instead, iterate over the items in the array:

```
def make_great(magicians):    
    for i in range(len(magicians)):
        magicians[i] = "The Great" + magicians[i]
```

Or use an enumerator as proposed above.  See: [How to modify list entries during for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop)

Answer (score 5):

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) would be the best thing to do in this case, then modify the value at each index in the array.

```
for i, magician in enumerate(magicians):
    magicians[i] = "the Great " + magician
```

Comment: Both you and @julienc have great answers although you should explain why the answer is what it is

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a little Python `magic` combining `lambda` and `map` [together](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~erdmann/mse350/topics/list_comprehensions.html)

```
>>> magicians = ['hudini', 'angel', 'teller', 'anderson', 'copperfield']
>>> map(lambda el:'pre_'+el,magicians)
['pre_hudini', 'pre_angel', 'pre_teller', 'pre_anderson', 'pre_copperfield']
```

Try it out [here](https://repl.it/C6ti/0)