# Use Python csv module to merge multiline cells with space or other characters

Tags: python, csv

I wrote a small script in Python to accept a csv file similar to what comes from Excel and output it as a pipe delimited file. When encountering a cell containing multiple lines, it currently adds a backslash (as that is what I specified as the escape character) at the end of the line and continues the cell on the next line. What I want to do though is be able to specify a space character or a string that the new line would be replaced with instead of the backslash and continue the record on the same line. I am having some trouble accomplishing this though. Is there an easy way to do this using the csv module? What I have so far:

```
fout = open (tfile, "wt")
cout = csv.writer(fout, delimiter = '|', quotechar = '', quoting =     csv.QUOTE_NONE, lineterminator = '\n', escapechar='\\')

cin = csv.reader(fin)

for row in cin:
    cout.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the answer to my issue. Instead of using a backslash as the escape character, I use '\n' and then do a find and replace of the new line for every field in each row. I.e.

```
cout = csv.writer(fout, delimiter = '|', quotechar = '', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE, lineterminator = '\n', escapechar='\n')
```

and

```
for row in cin:
    newrow = row
    row[:] = [str.replace("\n", " ") for str in row]
    cout.writerow(newrow)
```

The find and replace of the list is based on the response to [How to modify list entries during for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop)