# Editing items in a list of strings

Tags: python, list

**Scenario:** I have a list of strings that contains multiple file names. I am trying to either create a new list with just a part of each name, or to edit the original list to have just the part I wan. For example:

Original first item of list:

```
"iteration5_test1_part1.txt"
```

Wanted result:

```
"iteration5"
```

(basically I want to keep only what comes before the first underscore)

Although I read here [How to modify list entries during for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop) that it is not good practice to edit a list, I don't know any others ways to do it, so I am trying:

```
mypath = "/DGMS/Destop/uploaded"
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

for f in onlyfiles:
    f = f.split("_")
    f = f[0]
```

But unfortunately, this does not change the list in the wanted way.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for loop binds the name `f` to the individual strings in the list, and then your loop body simply rebinds the name.  This won't affect the list at all, it simply binds the name to a new string you create and then discards it before entering the next loop iteration.  I recommend reading [this article by Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) for a  more in-depth explanation of how Python names and assignments work.

The easiest solution is to use a list comprehension instead:

```
onlyfiles = [name.split("_")[0] for name in onlyfiles]
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Python are immutable, meaning they cannot be modified in-place.

You will have to re-assign the modified string to the list.

```
L = ["iteration5_test1_part1.txt"]

for index, item in enumerate(L):
    L[index] = item.split('_')[0]

print(L) # ['iteration5']
```

or as a list comprehension:

```
L = [item.split('_')[0] for item in L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mypath = "/DGMS/Destop/uploaded"

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

onlyfiles = [f.split("_")[0] for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
for i in range(len(onlyfiles)):
    temp = onlyfiles[i].split("_")[0]
    onlyfiles[i]=temp
```

will help.

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple matter of splitting the string using a delimiter.

```
>>> [s.split('_')[0] for s in l]
```

#driver values:

```
IN : l = ["iteration5_test1_part1.txt", "hello_world", "abc_"]
OUT : ['iteration5', 'hello', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to create a new list

```
mypath = "/DGMS/Destop/uploaded"
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
new_list = []
for f in onlyfiles:
    f = f.split("_")
    new_list.append(f[0])
```