# Splitting Post Codes from a List

Tags: python, list, loops, split, postal-code

I have a got a list of Post Codes that I would like to return just the first part of it.

```py
postcodes = list(df['postcode'][0:10])
```

> ['EC4V 3EJ', 'SE1 9DW', 'W12 7EY', 'E14 9GA', 'E17 8ES', 'N10 3LR', 'W2 2RH', 'W3 7ST', 'W2 1PW', 'W4 5RG']

```py
for p in postcodes:
    postcodes.append(p.split()[0])
postcodes
```

I was expecting to get something like:

```
['EC4V', 'SE1', 'W12', 'E14' ...]
```

but my kernel keeps looping and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Do not add to same list while iterating over. Change to something like `new_postcodes.append(p.split()[0])`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify list entries during for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop)

Answer (score 2):

You're looping over a list and appending to it in every iteration. Your loop will never stop (each member you loop over, you add another element to the list). You should use a list comprehension for your desired output:

```py
In [1]: l = ['EC4V 3EJ', 'SE1 9DW', 'W12 7EY', 'E14 9GA', 'E17 8ES', 'N10 3LR', 'W2 2RH', 'W3 7ST', 'W2 1PW', 'W4 5RG
   ...: ']

In [2]: [p.split()[0] for p in l]
Out[2]: ['EC4V', 'SE1', 'W12', 'E14', 'E17', 'N10', 'W2', 'W3', 'W2', 'W4']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're appending to `postcodes` while looping through postcodes. So you're never able to loop through everything in `postcodes` as you keep adding to it each loop. Instead, you can create a new empty list such as `modified_postcodes` which you can append each modified postcode to:

```
modified_postcodes = []
for p in postcodes:
    modified_postcodes.append(p.split()[0])

print(modified_postcodes)
```

Alternatively, you could use pythons `map` method to map each postcode in `postcodes` to its first segment by using `.split()`:

```
postcodes = ['EC4V 3EJ', 'SE1 9DW', 'W12 7EY', 'E14 9GA', 'E17 8ES', 'N10 3LR', 'W2 2RH', 'W3 7ST', 'W2 1PW', 'W4 5RG']
res = list(map(lambda p : p.split()[0], postcodes))
print(res)
```