# Why does enumerating over a list to delete items from it work?

Tags: python

```
l = [1,2,3,4] * 10
for idx, n in enumerate(l):
    if n == 3: del l[idx]
```

This works, giving `[1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4 ...]`. Why? Shouldn't the first deletion throw all the indices off? Is Python silently modifying its behavior DWIM-style?

Comment: Because you don't have repeating elements

Comment: it works because there are no adjacent threes. Try: `[1, 2, 3, 3]` and it will break.

Comment: Deletion throws the indices off, yes, but the real indices of all the threes are also decremented! So these mistakes cancel eachother out.

Comment: @wim So it does... I don't understand why it doesn't delete any non-3s though. Does the `enumerate` work off the live list and not a copy? Why doesn't Python yell at me for modifying something while iterating over it then?

Comment: Yes, enumerate works off the live list. It's a "feature" for lists, because you can actually safely iterate and modify if you know what you're doing (deleting in *reverse* iteration, for example).  Python will yell at you if you try the same thing for a dict...

Comment: @wim You should upgrade that to an answer.

Comment: @alkasm What exactly will break? Deleting one element, then further iterate will only leap over the next element of the list.

Comment: Deleting during reverse iteration takes overall worst-case quadratic time, though, so it's still a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually **isn't** iterating over all the elements, it's just that your code misses that fact.

You can demonstrate that with the following, which doesn't print anything:

```
l = [1,2,3,4] * 10
for idx, n in enumerate(l):
    if n == 3: del l[idx]
    elif n == 4: print('saw 4')
```

You might be interested in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4082739/355230) to the related question [How to modify list entries during for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop)