# Condition to convert NoneType into a string

Tags: python, nonetype

I have this python code, I want to convert the NoneType variable into a string, so I wrote this condition to catch it, but i'm unable to overwrite it. How can that be done ? Thanks

```
int_list= ['10','3',None,'5','8']
i = 0
for l in int_list:
    if l is None:
        l == 'hello'
    print l
    i+=1
```

Expected Output:

```
10
3
hello
5
8
```

Comment: your "list" is actually a tuple so you won't be able to modify it in-place, if it was a list you would do something along the lines of `int_list[i] = 'hello'` since just reassigning the local variable `l` doesn't even attempt to modify the original list.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python list tuple tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  Your code does not attempt to change `int_list`.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I tried with a list l = [], I want to assign a var type from that condition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify list entries during for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just changing the value of a variable `l`, currently containing an element in `int_list`, **not the list itself**.

You need to reassign the element in the list with a new value, using the `index` (here, `i`) to access this element in the list object.

Do this:

```
int_list= ['10','3',None,'5','8']
i = 0
for i in range(len(int_list)):
    if int_list[i] is None:
        int_list[i] = 'hello'  # accessing element IN THE LIST as index/position i, reassigning it to the new value 'hello'
    i+=1
print(int_list)
```

Output:

```
['10', '3', 'hello', '5', '8']
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the conditional test as an assignment. This will not work. Instead, try:

```
int_list= ['10','3',None,'5','8']
i = 0
for l in int_list:
    if l is None:
        l = 'hello'
    print l
    i+=1
```

In short, replace the `==` in your fifth with a single `=`. Hope that helps.

Comment: I think he wants to convert it, not just print it, so that won't work ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't convert it outside the condition, I want to assign a type ( string )

Comment: @aliouawalid you want to make int_list a list of strings, no matter what the type?