# Python Loop over Multiple Dataframes

Tags: python, function, dataframe, loops, list-comprehension

I would like to loop over two dataframes df1 and df2. These frames have the same columns and I would like to remove rows containing 12 as a value in col2.

The code that works for a single datafareme is the below:

```
df1 = df1[df1['col2'] != 12]
```

I have tried to create a list and loop over this list but is seem incorrect:

```
y = [df1, df2]

for x in y:
    x = x[x['col2'] != 12]
```

Comment: You are reassigning `x` inside the loop.  Your loop doesn't modify the original dfs in place, but rather, creates a filtered copy of each (that you immediately discard).

Comment: It may be easier to just [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the two dataframes into one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify list entries during for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop)

Comment: Thank you@0x5453, are you able to provide the correct code as an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *0x5453* noticed, you need to change the dataframes in place, like this for example :

```
y = [df1, df2]
for i, x in enumerate(y):
    y[i] = x[x['col2'] != 12]
```

Comment: Thank you @phoenixo, can I modify each single df with the loop? so if I print df1 or df2 I will get the output without 12 as a value..

Comment: Yes the for loop is modifying all df, so if you print them at the end you will get the expected result without value 12