# Why can I not increment a list this way in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, increment

Language is Python. I am trying to add 'a' to all of the values in a list 'sumarr'.

Here is my code:

```
for b in sumarr:
    b+=a
```

Why does this not work? I know I can use list comprehensions like this:

```
sumarr = [b+a for b in sumarr]
```

But why does the first method not work?

Comment: you can't change the value when it's in iteration

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop

Comment: Because `b+=a` creates a new `int` object, the result of `b + a` and then assigns that new object to the variable `b`. You never once mutate the list in that operation

Comment: @ZhubeiFederer sure you can.

Comment: you really should read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: So this is no more mysterious than the following: `a = 42; b = a; a = 0; print(b)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

b is a local variable - a *reference* of the list item, not the actual item in list.

If you do `print( b += a )` you will see the expected number, but it won't put that result back into your list.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

sumarr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a = 3

for b in range( len(sumarr) ):
    sumarr[b] += a

for b in sumarr:
    print( b )
```

4
5
6
7

Comment: "a local copy of the list item, not the actual item in list." Absolutely not true. It is the same object in the itself. Iterating over a list does not create copies. The rest of your answer is fine, but that first part is just not true.

Comment: It's not a deep copy, but a pointer to the address.  b is a variable that points TO the item - it's not THE item.

Comment: No **it isn't a copy at all**. Python *doesn't have pointers*. All variables act like references, yes, but that isn't relevant here and just obscures the straight-forward semantics. You can prove this easily: `data = [[]]` then `for sub in data: sub.append(42)` then `print(data)`. Of course, *assignment doesn't mutate*, which is the reason why simply assigning to a local variable has no visible effect on the list. So if I did, `for sub in data: sub = [99]` and `print(data)` it won't change

Answer (score 0):

Because this is not how python works.

> I am trying to add 'a' to all of the values in a list 'sumarr'

There are methods defined in python Data Structure:
[here the documentation python 3.9.0](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#:%7E:text=Extend%20the%20list%20by%20appending,len(a)%3A%5D%20%3D%20iterable%20.&text=Insert%20an%20item%20at%20a,a.append(x)%20.)

These are some official ways you can use to add elements in list.

```
# example 1.
new_list = []
for i in range(n):
  new_list.append(i) 

# List comprehension:
new_list = [i for i in range(n)]

# example 2.
lang = "Python"
a = []
for e in lang:
    a.append(ord(e))

b = [ord(e) for e in lang]

print(a)
print(b)
```