# Modifying a list item in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a html file (pulled via curl; to avoid pinging the website with my trials), which contains dog listing, and where I am interested in the h3 tag contents, which is the dog's name.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# read from previously saved file
url  = "petrescue_short.html"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")

# print all h3 tags; find_all returns a list! (not array)
h3_headers = soup.find_all(['h3'])
print('List all h3 header tags :', *h3_headers, sep='\n\n')
```

This will provide the result of:

```
<h3>
dog1
</h3>

<h3>
dog2
</h3>

...
```

However, I want to get rid of the tags or at least of the newlines, and tried all sorts of things that ended up in an error message `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`.
I also read this: [How to modify list entries during for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop) but the list shown there is actually an array.

I sort of understand that list are not arrays, but isn't there a way to iterate through the list (which I can do) AND if I cannot change the list item, at least assign it to another variable and modify it?

I would have thought the following should work:

```
for i in range(len(h3_headers)):
    h3_item = h3_headers[i]
    h3_item = h3_item.replace('\n', '')
    print(h3_item, sep='\n')
```

How can I achieve the following:

```
<h3>dog1</h3>
<h3>dog2</h3>
<h3>...</h3>
```

Comment: Cant you just loop `h3_headers` and get the dog names using `.text`? Something like `dogs = [each.text for each in h3_headers]`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply try to catch this tag within a regex, something like this would work

```
>>>import re
>>> temp = """<h3>
... dog1
... </h3>
... 
... <h3>
... dog2
... </h3>"""
>>> temp = temp.replace("\n", "")
>>> re.findall(r'<h3>(.*?)</h3>', temp, re.MULTILINE)
['dog1', 'dog2']
>>>
```

Comment: results in : `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'replace'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Comment: ResultSet is a list , I took temp as a string , in case you have temp as a list , you can do "".join(temp) and than call findall on it

Answer (score 0):

First thing is when you are printing your data using this,
print('List all h3 header tags :', *h3_headers, sep='\n\n')remove (, sep='\n\n') from print

Comment: :) that's not the issue `sep='\n\n'` adds 2 newlines to the output of each name in tags. It is not responsible of the newlines in the source.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in python are copied by value and not by reference. This means that when you write `a = values[1]` `a` is now a copy of `values[1]`, so changing `a` does not change `values[1]`. Instead of this you should modify your list directly, for example:

```
for i in range(len(h3_headers)):
    h3_item = h3_headers[i].replace('\n', '') ## a changed copy of h3_headers[i]
    h3_headers[i] = h3_item ## now the list is modified
    print(h3_item, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
<h3>dog1</h3>
<h3>dog2</h3>
```

Comment: hmm, I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` when trying this code.

Comment: Thats weird. Here is the full code: 

`h3_headers = []
h3_headers.append("""<h3>
dog1
</h3>""")
h3_headers.append("""<h3>
dog2
</h3>""")

for i in range(len(h3_headers)):
    h3_item = h3_headers[i].replace('\n', '') ## a changed copy of h3_headers[i]
    h3_headers[i] = h3_item
    print(h3_item, sep='\n')`.

I ran it on python version 3.7.7 on a windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

adding .text in the second line did it...

```
for i in range(len(h3_headers)):
    h3_item = h3_headers[i].text
    h3_item = h3_item.replace('\n', '')
    print(h3_item, sep='\n')
```

thanks :)