# Is there a way to rstrip the same character from every item in a list?

Tags: python, list, strip

I'm trying to strip a colon (':') from every string in a list of 1000 strings.  So far, I've tried using a map function with a rstrip and just a strip function but have had no luck. I also tried a simpler for loop function as seen below.

I'm not getting any errors, but when I try to print char it doesn't remove the colons

```
char = ['g:', 'l:', 'q:'] #in my actual code there are 1000 strings

for i in range(0,999):
  char[i].strip(':')
```

and also

```
for i in range(0,999):
   char[i].rstrip(':')
```

Comment: That *is* how you do it, but `char[i].strip(':')` creates a **new** string object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is there a way I can write that string object back into my list? Also, what happens to the string object I've created. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: "In-place": `char[:] = [ch.rstrip(':') for ch in char]`. See [How to modify list entries during for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`str.strip()` return a **new** `str` object. It doesn't change the original. So the loop should be something like this.

```py
for i in range(0,999):
  char[i]=char[i].strip(':')
```

Or better use list comprehension

```py
char=[x.strip(':') for x in char]
```