# Python: How to change the data type of every element in every sublist of a list. In this case: int to str

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, integer, sublist

Given a list like list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], in order to get back [['1','2','3'],['4','5,'6']], I have tried this:

```
for i in list1:
   for j in i:
      j = str(j)
list1
```

which does nothing to the list: it outputs list1 unchanged. I though it would work by reassigning, something like a[0][0] = str(a[0][0]) (which does work) in a loop. Of course, the for loop above won't do that.

Also tried "map", as in

```
for i in list1:
   for j in i:
      list(map(str,i)
```

which also doesn absolutely nothing to list1.

I am trying to alter the original list, which should be possible. Maybe a new list would be the case, but I'm almost sure it's unnecessary.

Can someone help?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `list1 = [list(map(str, sublist)) for sublist in list1]` or something

Comment: read here https://stackoverflow.com/q/4081217/3700626

Answer (score 0):

You can try list comprehension

```py
[[str(j) for j in i] for i in list1]
# or
# [list(map(str,i)) for i in list1]
```

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nested list comperhension

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
[[str(x) for x in y] for y in list1]
```

will return

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
```

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use map function somehow like this:

```
def convert(x=[]):
    return [str(i) for i in x]

>>list(map(convert,x))
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please check out [mutable/immutable objects](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747) in Python**

```
for i in list1:    # i is a list(mutable)
    for j in i:    # j is an int(immutable) 
        j = str(j) # j reference to new string object
```

**int is immutable** (not allow changes after creation), so this line

```
j = str(j)
```

created a new string object referred by j and the object in list i remains unchanged.

**list, dict, set, byte array are mutable objects.**

Changing the object value in a list can be done like this:

```
for i in list1:              # i is a list(mutable)
    for j in range(len(i)):  # this time, j is index of list i 
        i[j] = str(i[j])     # change the list values
```

And the result,

```
list1
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
```