# Deleting negative numbers from a list

Tags: python, list, function

I'm trying to do a function which deletes the negative numbers from a list that given externally and returns the new list. But my code gives me **"IndexError: list index out of range"** error. How can I fix it?

```
class Prtc:
def __init__(self, x, _lst):
    self.x = x
    self._lst = _lst
    
def del_neg(self, _lst):
    i = 0
    while i < len(_lst):
        if _lst[i] < 0:
            _lst.remove(i)
        i += 1
    return _lst
```

Comment: Please indent properly and include code that demonstrates the behavior you claim.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify list entries during for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop)

Comment: @ack That's not about deleting elements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is everytime you remove `i` you actually shorten the list here is a quick fix:

```py
class Prtc:
    def __init__(self, x, _lst):
        self.x = x
        self._lst = _lst
        
    def del_neg(self, _lst):
        i = 0
        while i < len(_lst):
            if _lst[i] < 0:
                _lst.remove(_lst[i])
                i -= 1
            i += 1
        return _lst
```

That said, there are **much** more efficient ways of doing this:

```py
def del_neg(self, _lst):
    return [item for item in _lst if item >= 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

As [LPR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67130263/5499386) said the problem is that you shorten the list every time you delete an item. The usual way that one can do this without playing with indices too much is going in reverse:

```
class Prtc:
def __init__(self, x, _lst):
    self.x = x
    self._lst = _lst
    
def del_neg(self, _lst):
    i = len(_lst) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        if _lst[i] < 0:
            _lst.remove(i)
        i -= 1
    return _lst
```

Although if you don't need to do it manually you should go with his second code, that being the most *pythonic* way of doing it