# Why is class collision not working in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I'm making a game where you throw snowballs at snowmen. Here are the definitions for the `Snowman` class and `Snowball` class:

```
class Snowman:
    def __init__(self,start,end,a,b):
        self.x = random.randrange(0,310)
        self.y = 0
        self.r = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,a,b)

class Snowball:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.x = mousex
        self.y = mousey
        self.r = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,a,b)
```

As you can see, the `r` attribute for the classes is their rectangle.

Below is a script that controls the snowman AI.

```
for s in snowmen:
    s.y += 0.5
    #above_makes_the_snowmen_approach_the_bottom_of_the_screen.
    #below_is_supposed_to_check_for_snowball_collision.
    for b in bullets:
        if s.r.colliderect(b.r):
            snowmen.remove(s)
            bullets.remove(b)
        print(b.r.colliderect(s.r))
        #above_is_a_debugger_that_reports_the_collision.
    if s.y < 640:
        blit(asnowman,(50,78),(s.x,s.y))
    else:
        snowmen.remove(s)
```

The problem is when I throw a snowball at one of the snowmen, the debugger reports `False` and the snowman doesn't die. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your code is (potentially) removing items in the two lists *while* it is iterating over them, which is always error prone.

Comment: The script is supposed to destroy both the snowman and the snowball upon impact

Comment: I understand that. The problem is that it does so inside a `for` loop that is iterating over the list. See this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop/4082739#4082739) on the topic (and how to work around it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907). You need to update the position of the rectangles before the collision test:

```py
s.r.topleft = round(s.x), round(s.y)
b.r.topleft = round(b.x), round(b.y)
if s.r.colliderect(b.r):
```

Note, you cannot get rid of the `x` and `y` attribute, because [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is supposed to represent an area on the screen and a `pygame.Rect` object can only store integral data.

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

---

Also read [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating). A possible solution could be to iterate through copies of the list:

```py
for s in snowmen[:]:
    s.y += 0.5
    s.r.topleft = round(s.x), round(s.y)
    for b in bullets[:]:
        b.r.topleft = round(b.x), round(b.y)
        if s.r.colliderect(b.r):
            snowmen.remove(s)
            bullets.remove(b)
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

While you initialize the `Rect` object in each of your classes to match the `x` and `y` attributes when the object is created, they do not remain in sync. That means that you only ever collide the rectangles *at their initial positions*, not where the objects have moved to later on.

The easiest way to solve this is probably to add a few lines of code to update `s.r` and/or `b.r`, but you could also start using `pygame.sprite.Sprite`, which will update its `rect` attribute to match its `x` and `y` attributes (and vice versa, I think). If you wanted to make your own classes behave a little bit like a `Sprite` without going all the way, I'd suggest making `x` and `y` into `property` descriptors, which reference the `Rect`, which becomes the single source of truth:

```
class Snowman:
    def __init__(self,start,end,a,b):
        self.r = pygame.Rect(random.randrange(0,310),0,a,b)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.r.left
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self.r.left = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.r.top
    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self.r.top = value
```