# KeyError 0 when deleting JSON key with value

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary, keyerror

I try to write script for deleting JSON fragment.
Currently I stopped with deleting key and value.
I get key error 0:

```
File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
KeyError: 0
```

I use `json` module and Python 2.7.

My sample json file is this:

```
"1": {
    "aaa": "234235",
    "bbb": "sfd",
    "date": "01.01.2022",
    "ccc": "456",
    "ddd": "dghgdehs"
},
"2": {
    "aaa": "544634436",
    "bbb": "rgdfhfdsh",
    "date": "01.01.2022",
    "ccc": "etw",
    "ddd": "sgedsry"
}
```

And faulty code is this:

```
import json

obj  = json.load(open("aaa.json"))

for i in xrange(len(obj)):
    if obj[i]["date"] == "01.01.2022":
        obj.pop(i)
        break
```

What I do wrong here?

Comment: That's not even valid JSON. Did you omit the outer `{}`?

Comment: Python 2 is end-of-life. Consider upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

`i` will take on the integer values `0`, `1`, but your object is a dictionary with string keys `"1"`, `"2"`. So iterate over the keys instead, which is simply done like this:

```
for i in obj:
    if obj[i]["date"] == "01.01.2022":
        obj.pop(i)
        break
```

Comment: Thanks! this ended with KeyError: 'date'

Comment: Not for me. But you are still not showing valid JSON input in your question, so who knows what you are actually doing?

Comment: Well, I pasted the given sample into square brackets :  {}, and now get something like:     {u'date': u'01.01.2022', u'aaa': u'234235', u'bbb': u'sfd', u'ccc': u'456', u'ddd': u'dghgdehs'}

Comment: `{}` are curly braces; square brackets are `[]`.

Comment: sorry, overwriting; pasted in curly braces

Answer (score 0):

The way you're reading it in, `obj` is a `dict`. You're trying to access it as a list, with integer indices. This code:

```
for i in range(len(obj)):
    if obj[i]["date"] == "Your Date":
        ...
```

First calls `obj[0]["date"]`, then `obj[1]["date"]`, and so on. Since `obj` is not a list, `0` here is interpreted here as a key - and since `obj` doesn't have a key `0`, you get a `KeyError`.

A better way to do this would be to iterate through the dict by keys and values:

```
for k, v in obj.items():
    if v["date"] == "your date":  # index using the value
        obj.pop(k)                # delete the key
```

Comment: Changing the object you are iterating-over doesn't work. There are ways to accomplish the same thing however — see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop/4082739#4082739)  to a question on the topic (which also applies to dictionaries).

Comment: Thanks! this ended with KeyError: 'date'

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, range yields integers, the first being 0. The is no integer as key in your json so this immediately raises a KeyError.

Instead, loop over `obj.items()` which yields key-value pairs. Since some of your entries are not `dict` themselves, you will need to be careful with accessing **`obj[i]['date']`**.

```
if isinstance(v, dict) and v.get("date") == "01.01.2022":
    obj.pop(k)
    break
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I dont get error message, but console window stays empty; the input file remained the same