# Understanding the Role of 'i = i + 1' in a Python For Loop Incrementation

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new to programming and trying to learn for loops. My question is regarding the following code:

```
numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]

i = 0
for number in numbers:
    number = number + 1
    numbers[i] = number
    i = i + 1

print(numbers)
```

What is the purpose of  i = i + 1? If we are trying to increment the value of each element in the list, number = number + 1 does that for us. Why use this additional line for incrementation?
Thank you in advance.

I tried taking out  i = i + 1 but it did not work as intended.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop - likely relevant.

Comment: See it in action at http://pythontutor.com; that’s probably the best way to understand it.

Comment: It's not good code in the first place, and not an appropriate example to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

`number` in the body of the loop is a *copy* of the element in the list. Incrementing it does not affect the original element. The `numbers[i] = number` line overwrites the original value with the updated one. But for that to work you need to track the index of the current element because `for ... in ...` does not do that, it only returns elements themselves, so extra variable `i` is introduced to do that and it has to be incremented on each iteration to keep up with the element processed.

Better way to do it would be

```
for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
    number = number + 1
    numbers[i] = number
```

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function provides indexes as well as elements, so no need to explicitly track the index on your own.

Comment: @OysterShucker, now explain that to a novice. Also, it does not increment each element by 1, and even if that is fixed, it creates a new array while the original code does in-place increments. So, strictly speaking, it is not equivalent although observable results are the same.

Comment: Oops, I meant `n+1`, and I guess I didn't need `enumerate`. I could easily explain it to a novice. It's just the exact same thing you wrote, but it doesn't have to re-reference the index to set it. It also doesn't change `numbers` while looping over it, but instead re-assigns `numbers` when the comprehension has completed. `numbers = [n+1 for n in numbers]` - is what I would have written if I would have been more mentally diligent.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers[i] = number
i = i + 1
```

The line you are asking about increments i by 1.  This is used with the line before to indicate which index in the `numbers` array to update.

It starts at 0 and ends at the length of the `numbers` array.

I am not sure how knowledge able you are about programming in general, so you may also want to research arrays if you do not understand how they work.

Answer (score 0):

This code can probably be made more self-explanatory by using better variable names.  In the version below I renamed the array from `numbers` to `evenNumbers`, I renamed `number` to `evenNumber`, and I renamed `i` to `indexIntoArray`.  I also added a debug-print so I can see what the values are at each iteration:

```
evenNumbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]

indexIntoArray = 0
for evenNumber in evenNumbers:
    print("At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is %i, evenNumber is %i, evenNumbers is %s" % (indexIntoArray, evenNumber, str(evenNumbers)))
    evenNumber = evenNumber + 1
    evenNumbers[indexIntoArray] = evenNumber
    indexIntoArray = indexIntoArray + 1

print(evenNumbers)
```

Running the code now gives this output:

```
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 0, evenNumber is 2, evenNumbers is [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 1, evenNumber is 4, evenNumbers is [3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 2, evenNumber is 6, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 3, evenNumber is 8, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 4, evenNumber is 10, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 5, evenNumber is 12, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 6, evenNumber is 14, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 7, evenNumber is 16, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 8, evenNumber is 18, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 9, evenNumber is 20, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 10, evenNumber is 22, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 11, evenNumber is 24, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 12, evenNumber is 26, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 13, evenNumber is 28, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 14, evenNumber is 30, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 15, evenNumber is 32, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 16, evenNumber is 34, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 34, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 17, evenNumber is 36, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 36, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 18, evenNumber is 38, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 38, 40]
At start of next iteration:  indexIntoArray is 19, evenNumber is 40, evenNumbers is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 40]
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41]
```

Given that, it should be obvious what is going on... `indexIntoArray` is used to keep track of which item in the array you want to increment, while `evenNumber` is locally holding the value of the `indexIntoArray`th item in the array.  If you never incremented `indexIntoArray`, then the only item in the array that you would ever change is the first one (i.e. `evenNumbers[0]`), which presumably isn't what you want.

If you are wondering why `evenNumber = evenNumber + 1` doesn't itself have a side effect of incrementing the value in the array, that is because `evenNumber` is a *copy of the value* of an array-item, not a reference/alias to an array-item.  `evenNumber` is its own separate/independent variable, so changing the value of `evenNumber` does not have any side-effects on anything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38]

# Use enumerate to get both the index (i) and the value (number)
for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
    numbers[i] = number + 1

print(numbers)
```

The enumerate function is useful here because it provides both the index (i) and the value (number) as you iterate over the list. You can then use i to update the list at the correct position.

Answer (score -1):

i is the index of the number in the numbers array.

If you remove i=i+1 this leaves the i in  numbers[i] undeclared which is why you get an error.

Comment: `i` isn’t undeclared and removing the incrementing operation doesn’t cause an *error*.